# Cannot modify C string

Tags: c, cstring

Consider the following code.

```
int main(void) {
    char * test = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    test[5] = 'x';
    printf("%s\n", test);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In my opinion, this should print abcdexghij. However, it just terminates without printing anything.

```
int main(void) {
    char * test = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    printf("%s\n", test);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This however, works just fine, so did I misunderstand the concept of manipulating C strings or something? In case it is important, I'm running Mac OS X 10.6 and it is a 32-bit binary I'm compiling.

Comment: I hate to say it, but this should really be in a C FAQ somewhere... it's been asked tens or hundreds of other times on Stack Overflow already.

Comment: I'm sorry if this had been asked before, however I was unable to find an answer. I really did read the function reference and everything first, but I really didn't see what I was doing wrong. Could you point me to such a C FAQ?

Comment: @x3ro: Nobody has answered you about a C FAQ in 4 years?? The [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) is excellent. Section 8 covers characters and strings, and question 8.5 points to question 1.32, which addresses your specific question.

Comment: This is like doing `int j = 5;` and then trying to turn that `5` into a `6`. You can change the value of `j` to `6`, but you can't turn that `5` itself into a `6`. You aren't trying to change the value of `test` here. You are trying to turn that string in your source code into something else!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Actually that's not quite right. `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` is stored in memory somewhere, and that memory can potentially be modified. It's location can't be changed, *that* would be like changing number 5 in your example. But its content can't be modified in modern operating systems only, because compiler makes it so that operating system will prevent the string modification. It'd be undefined behavior in the standard anyway, but I'm sure some C compilers define it as legal. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56743877/can-a-string-literal-in-c-be-modified

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1455982/827263) is good, but not quite complete.

```
char * test = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

A *string literal* refers to an anonymous array object of type `char[N]` with static storage duration (meaning it exists for the entire execution of the program), where `N` is the length of the string plus one for the terminating `'\0'`. This object is not `const`, but any attempt to modify it has undefined behavior. (An implementation *can* make string literals writable if it chooses, but most modern compilers do not.)

The declaration above creates such an anonymous object of type `char[27]`, and uses the address of that object's first element to initialize `test`. Thus an assignment like `test[5] = 'x'` attempts to modify the array, and has undefined behavior; typically it will crash your program. (The initialization uses the address because the literal is an expression of array type, which is implicitly converted in most contexts to a pointer to the array's first element.)

Note that in C++, string literals are actually `const`, and the above declaration would be illegal. In either C or C++, it's best to declare `test` as a pointer to *const* `char`:

```
const char *test = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

so the compiler will warn you if you attempt to modify the array via `test`.

(C string literals are not `const` for historical reasons. Before the 1989 ANSI C standard, the `const` keyword did not exist. Requiring it to be used in declarations like yours would have made for safer code, but it would have required existing code to be modified, something the ANSI committee tried to avoid. You should *pretend* that string literals are `const`, even though they aren't. If you happen to be using gcc, the `-Wwrite-strings` option will cause the compiler to treat string literals as `const` -- which makes gcc non-conforming.)

If you want to be able to modify the string that `test` refers to, you can define it like this:

```
char test[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

The compiler looks at the initializer to determine how big `test` needs to be. In this case, `test` will be of type `char[27]`. The string literal still refers to an anonymous mostly-read-only array object, but its value is *copied* into `test`. (A string literal in an initializer used to initialize an array object is one of the contexts in which an array does not "decay" to a pointer; the others are when it's the operand of unary `&` or `sizeof`.) Since there are no further references to the anonymous array, the compiler may optimize it away.

In this case, `test` itself is an array containing the 26 characters you specified, plus the `'\0'` terminator. That array's lifetime depends on where `test` is declared, which may or may not matter. For example, if you do this:

```
char *func(void) {
    char test[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    return test; /* BAD IDEA */
}
```

the caller will receive a pointer to something that no longer exists.  If you need to refer to the array outside the scope in which `test` is defined, you can define it as `static`, or you can allocate it using `malloc`:

```
char *test = malloc(27);
if (test == NULL) {
    /* error handling */
}
strcpy(test, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

so the array will continue to exist until you call `free()`. The non-standard `strdup()` function does this (it's defined by POSIX but not by ISO C).

Note carefully that `test` may be either a pointer or an array depending on how you declare it. If you pass `test` to a string function, or to any function that takes a `char*`, that doesn't matter, but something like `sizeof test` will behave very differently depending on whether `test` is a pointer or an array.

The [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) is excellent. Section 8 covers characters and strings, and question 8.5 points to question 1.32, which addresses your specific question. Section 6 covers the often confusing relationship between arrays and pointers.

Answer (score 36):

Char pointers defined with an initialization value go into a read-only segment.  To make them modifiable,  you either need to create them on the heap (e.g. with `new` operator or `malloc()` function) or define them as an array.

Not modifiable:

```
char * foo = "abc";
```

Modifiable:

```
char foo[] = "abc";
```

Comment: foo[0] = 'x' still segfaults on my box

Answer (score 4):

You should get into the habit of matching the type of the variable with the type of the initialiser. In this case:

```
const char* test = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

That way you will get a compiler error rather than a run-time error. Cranking your compiler warning level up to max may also help avoid such pitfalls. Why this is not an error in C is probably historical; early compilers allowed it and disallowing it might have broken too much existing code when the language was standardised. Now however operating systems do not allow it so it is academic.

Answer (score 4):

String literals may not be modifiable; it's best to assume they aren't.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-pointer-and-array/1341645#1341645) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
 char * bar = strdup(foo);
 bar[5] = 'x';
```

`strdup` makes a modifiable copy.

And yes, you should really test that `strdup` didn't return NULL.

Comment: ...and free(bar) at the end if you use strdup()!