# C Xor Encryption (beginner)

Tags: c

I found This Code for xor encryption and it works

```
string encryptDecrypt(string toEncrypt)
{
    char key = 'K'; //Any char will work
    string output = toEncrypt;
    int z = toEncrypt.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
    {
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key;
    }
    return output; 
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string encrypted = encryptDecrypt("kylewbanks.com");

    string decrypted = encryptDecrypt(encrypted);
    return 0;
}
```

but when I changed it to this form:

```
CHAR* encryptDecrypt(CHAR* toEncrypt)
{
     char key = 'K'; //Any char will work
     CHAR* output = toEncrypt;

     for (int i = 0; i < strlen(toEncrypt); i++)
     {
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key;
     }
     return output;
 }

 int main(int argc, CHAR* argv[])
 {
     CHAR* encrypted = encryptDecrypt("kylewbanks.com");
     CHAR* decrypted = encryptDecrypt(encrypted);
     return 0;
 }
```

the program break with this message: Access violation writing location 0x001CCC90

I need to use CHAR* or WCHAR* for my variable (I don't have permission to use string)

the questions are:

1- what is the problem in second code?

2- how can I change key to a word not a character?

thanks for help :)

**Edit:**

**the problem is that it breaks immediately after the line 7**

**it doesn't do this line at all:**

```
output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key;
```

Comment: `string` is not a standard C type and thus your problem cannot be easily reproduced. Are you sure this is not C++, or should include some non-standard header?

Comment: I said in my question I don't have permission to use string, I found a C++ code but I have to write a C code. and this is my problem...

Comment: This line `CHAR* encrypted = encryptDecrypt("kylewbanks.com");` attempts to change a *read-only* string (and I suspect the `string` declaration shielded that from you in the original). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455970/cannot-modify-c-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- what is the problem in second code?

As far as I understand you, you want to encrypt and decrypt a c-string. Strings in C are usually character arrays and terminated with a 0. Also you use the pointer arithmetics wrong here.

While:

```
string output = toEncrypt;
```

does a copy operation of the whole string,

```
CHAR* output = toEncrypt;
```

will just create a new pointer and let it point to the same point where the pointer `toEncrypt` points at atm. So at the end you just have 2 pointers pointing to the same position which is as good as using 1 pointer at all.

I would suggest that you make a new buffer in that method to store the encrypted data:

```
CHAR* output = new CHAR[strlen(toEncrypt)];
```

Though this could lead to undefined behavior if you don't encrypt zero terminated strings. As `strlen` would continue counting characters until it finds a `0`. So I also suggest you to send the lenght of the data to encrypt to your function:

```
CHAR* encryptDecrypt(CHAR* toEncrypt, int length)
```

Also readonly character initializations are always constant in C.

So a possible solution would be:

```
wchar_t* encryptDecrypt(const wchar_t* toEncrypt, int length)
{
    wchar_t key = L'K'; //Any char will work
    wchar_t* output = new wchar_t[length];  // Make a temporary buffer

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key; // Encrypt every char of the array to encrypt
    }
    return output;
}

int main(int argc, CHAR* argv[])
{
    // Your Data to encrypt / decrypt
    const wchar_t* sourceString = L"kylewbanks.com";
    const int sourceStrLen = wcslen(sourceString); // Get the lenght of your data before you encrypt it and can't use wcslen anymore. Alternatively just enter the amount of characters in your string here.

    // Encrypt / Decrypt your String
    wchar_t* encrypted = encryptDecrypt(sourceString, sourceStrLen);
    wchar_t* decrypted = encryptDecrypt(encrypted, sourceStrLen);

    // Free the allocated buffers
    delete[] encrypted;
    delete[] decrypted;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that if you want to display this string somewhere using methods like `printf()`, it will probably display some memory garbage after your string as the encryption returns just the encrypted data which is *not zero-terminated*.

> 2- how can I change key to a word not a character?

You could use several methods of XORing with the Key-String but one of the most simple ways would be to XOR the source string with the key-string over and over.

Something like:

```
    kylewbanks.com
XOR keykeykeykeyke
__________________
    RESULT
```

if your key-string is "key"

Possible solution:

```
wchar_t* encryptDecrypt(const wchar_t* toEncrypt, int length)
{
    const wchar_t* key = L"KEY"; // A readonly wide String
    wchar_t* output = new wchar_t[length];  // Make a temporary buffer

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key[i % wcslen(key)];    // i % 3 wil be ascending between 0,1,2
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: thank you, this code works, would you please answer the second question? I want to xor with a word not a character, `wchar_t* key = L"prtas"`

Comment: @user3105142 okay I updated the answer with a solution for your second question. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

1, In `encryptDecrypt` `output` is a local variable and link to a static string area, it is readonly. Usually you need to create a buffer space and pass it into `encryptDecrypt`. `malloc` inside the function also works but you need to `free` it manually. BTW, `strlen` is also dangerous because the encrypted data may not be a valid string.

2, use `WCHAR` and `wcslen` instead of `CHAR` and `strlen`, key use `L'k'` should work.

Comment: I updated the answer too, edit using phone is pretty slow, sorry.