# Sort in alphabetically order random names in C

Tags: c, string, sorting, bubble-sort

I try to sort alphabetically some names but get the "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)" error when I try to copy one string to another using bubble sort method.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *string[] = {"Nickole", "Bolden", "Eldon", "Darcie", "Lisette", "Furr", "Parthenia", "Tunison", "Andrew", "Michael"};
    char *hold;
    int compare_a, compare_b;
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            compare_a = string[i][0];
            compare_b = string[i+1][0];
            if( compare_a > compare_b) {           
                strcpy(hold, string[i+1]);
                strcpy(string[i+1], string[i]);
                strcpy(string[i], hold);
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("%s ", string[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `string` is an array of string literals. You cannot write over this memory with `strcpy()`.

Comment: Instead of copying the strings, you should just swap the pointers to each string.

Comment: You cannot modify a string literal. Also, there are countless of examples of how to sort an array of pointers to char alphabetically if you google for them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with "char \*s" but not "char s\[\]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings you have in your program are string literals. Literals are like constants and attempts to modify them leads to undefined behaviour though they are not specified as `const`. They may be placed in a part of memory from which the program will only be able to read but not write.

You attempt to modify the memory where the string literals are stored with your `strcpy()`s. You got a segmentation fault because you invoked undefined behaviour.

Now your program would've worked had you declared the strings like

```
char string[][10] = {"Nickole", "Bolden", "Eldon", "Darcie", "Lisette", "Furr", "Parthenia", "Tunison", "Andrew", "Michael"};
```

I gave the size as 10 as the longest string here is of length 9. One byte extra for the `\0` character indicating end of string.

This is because they are not string literals and may be modified.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19071536) post.

As Code-Apprentice suggested in the comments you could swap the values of pointers instead of attempting to swap string literals.

```
if( compare_a > compare_b) {
    hold=string[i];
    string[i]=string[i+1];
    string[i+1]=hold;
}
```

Also, you can use `strcmp()` for comparing strings instead of just comparing the first character of the strings like

```
if( strcmp(string[i], string[i+1])>0 ) {
    hold=string[i];
    string[i]=string[i+1];
    string[i+1]=hold;
}
```

[`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) returns positive value if the second string is before the first in the lexicographical order.

Comment: I got "error: assignment to expression with array type" at the line with 'hold=string[i]'

Answer (score 1):

The memory of `hold`is never allocated. With `strcpy(hold, ..)` that will be an issue. Better to use `char hold[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];` or allocate with `new` corrsponding Memory resources.

Additional the array `string` is a compile time constant Array which you can't override.