# Using strtok to split a string in c

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, c-strings, strtok, string-literals

In the code below I try to split a string to get names separated by "," from the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{
    char *st = "Addison,Jayden,Sofia,Michael,Andrew,Lily,Benjamin";
    char *name[7];
    char *separate = ",";

    char *token = strtok(st, separate);
    int i = 0;
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(name[i], token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        i++;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", name[j]);
    }
}
```

However, I run into segmentation fault when I try to run the code. I try to debug it and it seems that this specific line of code is where the error comes from:

```
char *token = strtok(st, separate);
```

Can anyone please tell me what did I do wrong?

Comment: `strcpy(name[i], token);` You have not initialized the pointers in the array. Simple solution: `char name[7][128];` Otherwise, you can use `malloc()`.

Comment: Oh right... if I use char *name, I will have to allocate memory to it using malloc() before use. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared a pointer to a string literal

```
char *st = "Addison,Jayden,Sofia,Michael,Andrew,Lily,Benjamin";
```

You may not change string literals. Any attempt to changve a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined**

On the other hand, the standard C function `strtok` changes the passed to it string.

From the C Standard (7.23.5.8 The strtok function)

> 4 The strtok function then searches from there for a character that is
> contained in the current separator string. If no such character is
> found, the current token extends to the end of the string pointed to
> by s1, and subsequent searches for a token will return a null pointer.
> **If such a character is found, it is overwritten by a null character,
> which terminates the current token.** The strtok function saves a
> pointer to the following  character, from which the next search for a
> token will start.

So substitute the declaration for

```
char st[] = "Addison,Jayden,Sofia,Michael,Andrew,Lily,Benjamin";
```

Also you declared an array of pointers that is not initialized.

```
char *name[7];
```

So this statement

```
strcpy(name[i], token);
```

also invokes undefined behavior.

Instead you could just write

```
name[i] = token;
```

And as the variable i contains the number of tfokens then in general this loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
{
    printf("%s\n", name[j]);
}
```

should be rewritten at least like (without using the magic number 7)

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    puts( name[j] );
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the problem of my code, after I copy the char * st to anther char array char str[], and pass the str as a parameter into strtok(), everything works fine now, but I still dont understand why I have to do it. What is the difference between a char* and a char array, I thought they are the same.

Comment: @heihei The original declaration char *st = /*...*/; declares a pointer to a string literal. You may not change the string literal. This declaration char * st[] = /*...*/; declares an array that is initialized by the elements of a string literal. You nay change any character of the array. And the function strtok changes passed to it string.

Answer (score 3):

*However, I run into segmentation fault when I try to run the code*

Two problems:

- Attempting to change a non-editable string.
- Attempt to access location not owned by process.

Either of these can result in a crash. (seg-fault)

*Memory allocation problem*:
The declaration:

```
  char *name[7];
```

Creates an array of 7 pointers.  Each of them require memory to be allocated before it can be used in this way:

```
strcpy(name[i], token);
```

Memory allocation example:

```
for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
{
    name[i] = malloc((maxNameLen+1)*sizeof(name[i]));
    if(!name[i]) 
    {
        //handle error
    }
}
//now each pointer has space for up to maxNameLen+1 characters
```

*Non-editable string*:

```
char *st = "Addison,Jayden,Sofia,Michael,Andrew,Lily,Benjamin";
```

A string to be edited cannot be in this form (i.e. a [string literal](https://www.cs.uic.edu/%7Ejbell/CourseNotes/C_Programming/CharacterStrings.html)).  It must be in an editable form in order for `strtok()` to *change* it, as it will when parsing.  There are many *string* forms that are editable, Here are two examples:

```
//Create an editable form:
char st[] = {"Addison,Jayden,Sofia,Michael,Andrew,Lily,Benjamin"};

//Create an editable copy of original: (requires freeing when done using)
char *duplicate = strdup(st);
if(duplicate)
{
    //success duplicating, now parse duplicate.
```

There is [another discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455970/cannot-modify-c-string) explaining editable/non-editable strings in C.

Comment: Thank you very much, forgot to allocate memory before using the pointer array.

Comment: Thank you for adding and explaining the non-editable string part.