# Array of Pointer for char Vs Array of pointer for int

Tags: c, pointers

Why the first declaration is valid whereas the other is not ?

```
    char* string[2] = { "Hello", "Bellow" };

    int* b[2] = { {1,2,3}, {2,3,4} };
```

Comment: Because in the first one, the (string literal) data resolves to the pointer type. In the second, the data is not pointers, and the definition should be `int b[2][3]`

Comment: There is a simpler version that shows the behaviour you talking about. Just a pointer, the array is not needed to show it. `const char *foo="blabla"; int *thisDoesNotWork={1,2,3,4};`

Comment: Well that i know , but the WHY i am not able to understand

Comment: You asking why the language designers made the decisions they did?

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533439/string-literals-vs-array-of-char-when-initializing-a-pointer

Comment: `string` should be `const char *string[2];` and not `char *string[2];`, since the string literals are `const`. (Not related to your question)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295147/initializing-char-pointer-as-string-vs-other-type-pointers-as-arrays

Comment: Ohh now im getting it , thanks a lot for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

In the declaration

```
char* string[2] = { "Hello", "Bellow" };
```

the string literals are not being used to initialize a character array, but an array of pointers, so both strings "decay" to pointers to their first element, so you get

```
char *[2] = { char *, char * };
```

In the other declaration

```
int* b[2] = { {1,2,3}, {2,3,4} };
```

`{1,2,3}` and `{2,3,4}` are not array *expressions* - they’re initializer lists, and they don’t "decay" to pointers.  As tstanisl shows, you can use *compound literals* like

```
int *b[2] = { (int[]){1,2,3}, (int[]){2,3,4} };
```

and each of the compound literal expressions will decay to a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the compiler is not able to imply the type from `{1,2,3}`, which is desired to be `int[3]`. You can use array literal to specify it manually as `int[3]` or `int[]`:

```
int *b[2] = { (int[]){1,2,3}, (int[]){2,3,4} };
```

However, you need to be careful because the lifetime of the literals is bound only to the block where they are defined.