# Why the data type conversion error comes only in C++ but not in C?

Tags: c++, c

I am not an expert in C++. I get an error when I try to execute the following line  in C++. However, I don't get this error in C. Can you please explain why does it happen so?

```
 int  policy;
 char *policy_name = (policy == SCHED_FIFO) ? "SCHED_FIFO" : (policy == SCHED_RR) ? "SCHED_RR" : (policy == SCHED_OTHER) ? "SCHED_OTHER":"??";
```

Compilation error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
```

If I do this, the error goes off.

```
 const char *policy_name = (policy == SCHED_FIFO) ? "SCHED_FIFO" : (policy == SCHED_RR) ? "SCHED_RR" : (policy == SCHED_OTHER) ? "SCHED_OTHER":"??";
```

The question is why does it happen so?

Comment: The error says it all. No error in C doesn't mean that you are safe with this in C. Indeed, you generate a segmentation fault if you really treat this immutable string as mutable lateron, even in C. It's just that your C++ compiler won't let you do it in the first place. For a good reason.

Comment: Either way, you should declare the variable as a `const char*` rather than a `char*` because those are constant string literals. Even though it may compile successfully, it would still invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: In C++, the type of a string literal is `const char[]`, but in C the type of a string literal is `char []`. [More details in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245664/string-literals-in-c).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The question is why does it happen so?

Because the type of `"SCHED_FIFO"` (and other *string-literals*) is `char const[N]`<sup>1</sup> which converts into `char const*`. That means, the type of right expression is `const char*` which cannot be assigned to `char*`.

```
char *policy_name = (policy == SCHED_FIFO) ? "SCHED_FIFO" :  .......
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    type of this expression is char const*
```

But once you make the left side `const char*` also<sup>2</sup> then it compiles fine!

Hope that helps.

---

<sup>1. where `N` is some **integral constant** value.

2. BTW, `const char*` and `char const*` are the same thing! I've this habit of writing `char const*` instead of `const char*`, but they're interchangeable.</sup>