# Why char variable in struct need to set as pointer variable only work?

Tags: c, pointers

```
struct telephone
{
    char *name;
    int number;
};

int main()
{
    struct telephone index;
    index.name = "Jane Doe";
    index.number = 12345;
    printf("Name: %s\n", index.name);
    printf("Telephone number: %d\n", index.number);

    return 0;
}
```

Can i know why char type need a pointer only can work, but int no need?

Comment: the `char *name` is an array of chars ;)

Comment: @demonking - not an *array* rather a pointer to type `char`. String literals are exceptions when using pointer assignments in the case of `char` type. But one needs to be careful and make sure if the string is dynamic, then the pointer to `char` must be allocated using `malloc` family of memory allocation functions or even `strdup`. **READ** this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2245983/206367) that explains why!

Comment: @demonking char[] name is an array of char. char* name is a pointer to a char.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a `char*` if that is what you want. Here name points to a sequence of `char`. If you want your `struct` to contain a single `char` than you can do so.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can put a `char` in a `struct`. Of course, in this case, it is only a `char`, not a pointer to `char` (i.e. `string` in C).

For example:

```
struct telephone
{
    char name;                            // a char
    int number;
};

int main()
{
    struct telephone index;
    index.name = 'a';                    // assign a char
    index.number = 12345;
    printf("Name: %c\n", index.name);    // print a char
    printf("Telephone number: %d\n", index.number);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The character needs to be a pointer because it is being used as a "string." That is what a string declaration looks like in C. The pointer points to the first character in the string. Adding +1 to the pointer will give you the next character in the C-String.

Answer (score 0):

You can you just char too. But it will be just a single character.
char* is a string (think of it like array of chars)
like int* is like a array of int.

the pointer points to the first character of the string.