# memcpy using pointers throwing access violation

Tags: c

I have a very simple c question regarding memcopy that I have been able to fix but not understand why. The following code crashes with an "access violation" at runtuime:

```
char *src = "HELLO WORLD!";
char * dest = "hello world!";
memcpy(dest, src, strlen(src)+1);
```

dest would appear to be big enough and as I understand it memcpy should just blindly copy the bytes so I don't understand the problem.

Changing dest to an array e.g `char dest[13];` fixes things, so is it a requirement that dest must be uninitialized memory and creating an array does this for you whereas the pointer declaration does not?

Cheers

Comment: Literal strings do not work this way. Create new buffers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you do:

```
char *dest = "hello world!";
```

`"hello world!"` is kept in the read-only parts of the memory and pointer named `dest` is pointed to it, making any writing operation on this memory illegal. So if you try to use it as  a destination in your `memcpy`; it's an access violation.

You should use:

```
char dest[] = "hello world!";
```

Answer (score 3):

A string literal, "...", when used to initialise a char pointer, has type const char *, i.e. it's read-only.

dest should therefore have type const char *, at which point your code won't compile.

If you turn all your compiler warnings on then you'll get a warning for the "char * dest = ..." line.

Comment: "...." is `char[]` and it is read only because it resides in read only section. And  `char* arr = malloc(6);
 const char* arrptr= arr;

 memcpy(arrptr,"hello",5);
 printf("%s",arrptr);` compiles without warnings at my machine

Comment: char foo[] = "..." and char *foo = "..." aren't the same thing. Regarding compiler warnings: gcc 4.8 with default warning options says "passing argument 1 of memcpy discards const qualifier", which is precisely the problem. Either investigate turning on more warnings, or (if possible) get a better compiler. It's also worth compiling with multiple compilers, because they all spot different things.

Comment: Regarding const-ness of "...": C99 section 6.4.5, paras 5, 6: "The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize an array ... If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: Regarding type of string literal read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2245983/2549281 .

Comment: Yes, but it's used in an initialiser, so you need also to read section 6.7.8 of the standard. In that char[] case you're initialising an array (para 14); in the char * case you're initialising a scalar (para 11).

Answer (score 1):

char dest [] = "hello world!" and char* dest = "hello world!" is not the same thing. char dest[]="hello world!" is an array with 13 elements (the string is null-terminated). char* dest ="hello world!" is a pointer to an constant, null terminated string (also 13 characters).