# Specialisation for template class constructor

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I am new to templates in C++.
Can anyone explain why my specialised constructor never gets executed.
It works when I remove the const and reference operator.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class CData
{
public:
    CData(const T&);
    CData(const char*&);
private:
    T m_Data;
};

template<typename T>
CData<T>::CData(const T& Val)
{
    cout << "Template" << endl;
    m_Data = Val;
}
template<>
CData<char*>::CData(const char* &Str)
{
    cout << "Char*" << endl;
    m_Data = new char[strlen(Str) + 1];
    strcpy(m_Data, Str);
}

void main()
{
    CData<int> obj1(10);
    CData<char*> obj2("Hello");
}
```

The output is

Template

Template

Comment: `main` must return `int`, not `void`. Also, the header for `strcpy` and `strlen` is `<cstring>`, not `<string>`.

Comment: A string literal is an array lvalue, which can be converted to a pointer prvalue. A pointer prvalue cannot bind to a non-const lvalue reference like `const char* &`. That's why the first ctor is called.

Comment: By the way, this isn't a partial specialization. It is an explicit specialization of a single member function.

Comment: Note that the selection of the first ctor in the second call uses a deprecated conversion: `const T&` for `T == char*` yields a `char* const&`, which requires converting the *array of 6 `const char`* of the string literal to a `char*` (non-const).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you cannot bind `"Hello"` to a `const char*&`.

The information [dyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp) added in comments is quite interesting:

> A string literal is an array lvalue, which can be converted to a pointer prvalue. A pointer prvalue cannot bind to a non-const lvalue reference like const char* &

Which means you can actually make it work by replacing `const char*&` by `const char* const&`,  or even `const char* &&` in c++11, not sure if this is really smart in your use case though.

Comment: *"Which means you can actually make it work"* Or you just use `const char*` without any reference. I'm not sure what the OP intends to do, though.

Comment: @Drax to match template declaration you should use `char* const&`.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** I got everything wrong, rewrote the answer completely.

First, this constructor

```
template<>
CData<char*>::CData(const char* &Str)
```

is not a specialization of `CData(const T&)`, because the `Str` parameter here is a *non-const reference* to pointer to `const char`. So it's a definition of non-templated constructor `CData(const char*&)`.

Second, `"Hello"` has type "array of n `const char`" (see [What is the type of string literals in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245664/string-literals-in-c)) so it can't be converted to non-const reference. This is why "Template" constructor is called.

The correct specialization is

```
template<>
CData<char*>::CData(char* const& Str)
```

That is, it accepts a const reference to `char*`.

And after that you should remove `CData(const char*&)`, unless you need for example this code to compile:

```
const char* foo = "foo";
CData<int> obj2(foo);
```

So here is the code:

```
template<typename T>
class CData
{
public:
    CData(const T&);
private:
    T m_Data;
};

template<typename T>
CData<T>::CData(const T& Val)
{
    ....
}

template<>
CData<char*>::CData(char* const& Str)
{
    ....
}

// warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
CData<char*> obj2("Hello"); // calls CData(char* const&)
```

The proper way of fixing above warning is to add another specialization:

```
template<>
CData<const char*>::CData(const char* const& Str)
{
    ...
}

CData<const char*> obj2("Hello"); // calls CData(const char* const&)
```

Comment: @dyp thanks, I corrected the answer. Regarding the link, C++ string literals are also covered there.

Comment: Oh, oops, I only read half of the first answer and glanced over the others.