# Why does this code work in C?

Tags: c, string

```
char *a= "ABC";
```

`"ABC"` string is of `const char*` type. How can its address be assigned to a `char*` pointer?
Shouldn't it be an error?

Comment: It's [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (see first example).

Comment: C is not as type-strict as C++ - that's the reason

Comment: `Char` is not a type in C. Do you mean `char`?

Comment: I'd recommend using [this FAQ topic](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html) as a starting point.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245664/string-literals-in-c

Comment: No, `"ABC"` is of type `char[4]`, which is implicitly converted to `char*` in most, but not all, contexts. (Attempting to modify a string literal has undefined behavior, but for historical reasons they're not `const`.)

Answer (score 3):

```
char *a = "ABC";
```

`"ABC"` is of type `char [4]` in C while it is of type `const char [4]` in C++.

Comment: Are you sure it is true in C99 and in C11 ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: That's the only kind of constant literal which is not `const`-modified...

Comment: I can't recall any different situation while modifying such string literal than segfault. So, "ABC" is of type char, but it is stored in read-only memory? That would make sense.

Comment: @mac: string literals can be pooled and may be stored in read-only memory, if such exists, just like and together with constant compound-literals. Their type is still not `const`-qualified in C, nor in C++03 and earlier (later versions fixed that, as heralded by it being deprecated then). There is no guarantee either happens, and there's no guarantee there is any read-only memory.

Answer (score 2):

String literals in C have types of non-const arrays. From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals):

> The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize an array
>   of static storage duration and length just sufficient to contain the
>   sequence. For character string literals, the array elements have
>   **type char**, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character sequence.

Though string literals in C have types of non-const arrays they shall not be modified.

> If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.

In this connection consider for example the declaration of standard C function `strchr`:)

`char *`strchr(`const char *`s, int c);

The function returns a pointer to the same string that as the parameter is defined with the qualifier const.

In C++ string literals have types of constant characters arrays.

From the C++ Standard

> 8 Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred
>   to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type
>   **“array of n const char”**, where n is the size of the string as defined below, and has static storage duration (3.7).