# Error in class type as an exception in c++

Tags: c++

Whenever I try this code to catch class type as exception I get an error message as "deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'" .

Why is it so and how can it be avoided?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class Error
{
 int err_code;
 char *err_desc;
public:
       Error(int c , char* p)
        {
           err_code=c;
           err_desc=new char(strlen(p));
           strcpy(err_desc,p);
        }
        void display(void)
         {
           cout<<err_code<<"done successfully"<<err_desc;
          }
      };
 int main()
{
int x;
try
 {
  cout<<"\n press any key to avoid exception except 99";
  cin>>x;
  if(x=99)
  throw Error(x,"Exception");
 }
catch (Error e )
 {

   cout<<"\n exception caught successfully";
   e.display();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string literal should be passed into a `const char*` not a `char*` ([the former is the correct type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245664/what-is-the-type-of-string-literals-in-c-and-c)) so change the constructor signature to

```
Error(int c , const char* p);
```

and the member variable to

```
const char *err_desc;
```

Or you can pass around `std::string`, which I would recommend.

Comment: ...or better yet, do the right thing and derive from std::runtime_error

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the type of a string literal is array of `const char`, so normally you would use it to initialize a `const char*`, not a `char*`. The special rule that you can nonetheless initialize a `char*` with a string literal, which is not really const-correct, is for backward compatibility with C, in which string literals are arrays of plain `char`. It was deprecated as of C++03, and removed in C++11.

You should change `err_desc` and the argument of `Error`'s constructor from `char*` to `const char*`, which will make the warning go away, as well as make your code const-correct and prevent it from breaking in C++11.