# String to char* in Xcode c++

Tags: c++, xcode, string, char

I write the code like this

```
class A{
// ...
public:
insert(int key, char* contents){ ... }
}
```

and want to use

```
A.insert(1, "hellow world");
```

but does not allow conversion from string literal to char*

how can use like this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the type of string literals in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245664/what-is-the-type-of-string-literals-in-c-and-c)

Comment: only using c++ string literal

Answer (score 0):

A string literal is a `const char*`.

```
class A{
    // ...
    public:
    insert(int key, const char* contents){ ... }
}

// ...
A.insert(1, "hello world");
```