# If I declare a function in c that takes address of a variable/array it should only work on passing address. Why does it works with constants too?

Tags: c, arrays, function, constants

Suppose the function definition be:

```
int    strlength    (char    str[])    {
            int    i;
            for(i=1;str[i]!='\0';i++);
            return    i;
        }
```

It should work only when passing the address of the first block of array i.e. '&str[0]' OR 'str' but it works even on passing a string constant let's say "AnswerPlease". Why?

Comment: Why do you thing is should not work " even on passing a string constant"?  `strlength()` does not attempt to modify the data pointed to by `str`?

Comment: String literals are some special stuff different from `char`s and `int`s. Using `"Blahblahblah"` actually stores the string literal somewhere in the memory, Unlike the others, say `'C'` where no memory is allocated for it. As the below answer says, a string literal is a `static const char[]` and you get the address of its first element just as in the case of arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the C standard says so.
In C the type of a string literal is a `char[]`, only it's `static` and `const`.

See [What is the type of string literals in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245664/what-is-the-type-of-string-literals-in-c-and-c) and [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents).