# C: How to append data to a file without using standard I/O libraries

Tags: c, system-calls, fcntl

I was wondering if there is a way to append data to a file without using functions from standard I/O libraries (i.e. `stdio.h`). I though of doing something like this first:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int fd = open("test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0700);
    ssize_t wr = write(fd, "hello world", sizeof("hello world");
}
```

But this only writes data to the file without appending it so instead repeatedly displaying "hello world", it only overwrites the previous data and displays it once. Can someone please help me out? Thanks

Comment: Try typing `man 2 open` and you will find the flags to use...

Comment: you can open the file in append mode or seek to the end but you're still essentially using the standard functions.  What's the motivation to avoid the proper file functions?

Comment: Also, `sizeof("hello world")` is 4, since you are asking for the size of the pointer.

Comment: @vy32 no `sizeof("hello world")` works because it is a _literal_ (okay it's not that good a practice). And sizeof a pointer is not always 4. We're in 2018 you know

Comment: your code has a typo in it

Comment: ' this only writes data to the file without appending it' no, it generates a 'mismatched brackets' comipile-time error.  Post only the code you actually tested, else you will waste everyone's time:(

Comment: @MartinJames don't kill the fun :)

Comment: Also, close the file!

Comment: @vy32 no, `sizeof("hello world")` is 12, because it's a `char[]`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2245983/1480131

Comment: Wow. I had no idea that sizeof(literal) was equiv to strlen(). That's broken. But I guess it makes sense.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int fd = open("test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0700);
    ssize_t wr = write(fd, "hello world", strlen("hello world");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I treid doing exactly what you did but it still doesn't work. I then tried using lseek() to seek to the end of the file, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: note that your code doesn't even compile

Comment: @M.Ahmed your code doesn't compile, the answer code doesn't compile, and works fine after fixing the typo. This question & answer is just useless, broken, duplicate stuff

Comment: Not all combos of flags are valid. Maybe write-only is incompatible with append, (how can the file system find the end if it is not allowed to read the file?).

Comment: So, that's both the OP and yourself that cannot count brackets:(

Comment: Does anyone bother to close files?  A compliant C will close files opened with fopen(), but if you bypass that, you may end up with buffered output discarded by the OS.

Comment: @MartinJames in that case, example is using unbuffered output. But yes, those youngsters nowadays...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre there is no guarantee of unbuffered output - just because you cannot see it in the C source or in the crt stdio buffer does not mean that the OS has not buffered it, and may discard that buffer from its I/O system before it is written if the process that owns/issued it is terminated:(

Comment: If OP wants an atomic operation, then the OP asked the wrong question. The OP should have asked how to get a lock on a file.