# Why does the C compiler allow me to use strcpy to overwrite string literal?

Tags: c, c-strings, strcpy

Why is the below code working in Visual Studio ?

```
char* str1 = "This is a test string";
strcpy_s(str1, strlen(str1), "replacing content");
```

My understanding is str1 is just a char* pointing to a string literal, and not to an array of chars.
And in strcpy_s() (or strcpy()), char bytes are copied from src to dst array.

In the above code, isn't strcpy() trying to overwrite a string literal ? If yes, then why is the code compiling ?

additional info

Not only is the code compiling, I can see the new string getting copied.

```
void stringCopy_demo() {    
    char* str1 = "1234567890"; //len = 10   
    printf("%s \n", str1);
    strcpy_s(str1, strlen(str1), "content");
    printf("%s \n", str1);  
}
```

ouput

```
1234567890
content
```

Comment: If the code compiles, have you tried to run it?

Comment: Just because it compiles doesn't mean it's "working"!

Comment: Assuming that your code does compile, I think you need to change the question to "why does the C compiler allow me to use strcpy to overwrite a string literal"?

Comment: It is undefined behaviour.  Anything may happen.  That inludes "appearing to work" and "crashing" and also modifying the string literals `"string"` and `"test string"` that are used elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @NovaSysEng Thanks. I have changed the title as per ur suggestion.

Comment: [C11 §6.4.5 String literals ¶6,7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6) says: _…The multibyte character
sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
sufficient to contain the sequence. … If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
undefined._

Comment: Did the compiler give you a warning?

Comment: Use the `const` modifier to protect yourself, `const char* str1 = "This is a test string";`. Suppose `str1` was supplied as a function argument and the initialisation was by the function caller. It would be unreasonable to expect the compiler to know it is a string literal. But now, the compiler will object.

Comment: Changed compiler to gcc. And Voila !!! Code crashes.

Comment: @TanM that is because you have *undefined behaviour*. This is not a value judgement about the code compilers produce - the results are unpredictable. What can be judged, is the warnings you are given by the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C99 string literals are `char[]`, but modifying the array is undefined behaviour, see [What is the type of string literals in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245664/what-is-the-type-of-string-literals-in-c-and-c)
.

Many compilers have options to enable warnings for non-const usage, e.g gcc's [-Wwrite-strings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)