# What is the difference in using variable as function argument and in using directly string as function argument?

Tags: c, function, arguments

I was making some function that takes string as function argument but

```
// This is working fine
char string[] = "Any string";
func(string);

//This is not working
func("Any string");
```

Please tell me the difference

Comment: If `func` tries to modify the string then passing a literal is undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes the function modify strings

Comment: please tell me what do you mean by "passing the literal is undefined behaviour."

Comment: Passing the literal is not undefined behavior.  But if the function attempts to change the value of the literal, then the attempt to change it is undefined, so passing a literal to the function will lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your description, it seems that the prototype of your function

```
func(char* str);
```

OR

```
func(char str[]);
```

Now the problem comes in the datatype of the String. When you call `func("Any string")` which is expecting a pointer value (as an Array also works as a pointer) you are giving it a string value which will generate an error as the arguments are miss-matched.

If you still want to pass a string use this:

```
str = "Any String";
func(str.toCharArray());
```

Comment: The “use” prescription looks more like C++ than C.  Do you want to rewrite in in C or explain how this works inC?  Or you can delete this.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference in using variable as function argument and in using directly string as function argument?

```
char string[] = "Any string";
func(string);
// VS.
func("Any string");
```

`string[]` is a character array initialized with the size and contents of `"Any string"`.

`"Any string"` is a *string literal*.

---

If `func()` is `func(const char *s)`, then no difference as `func()` simply is reading the string.

If `func()` is `func(char *s)`, yet does not modify the string pointed to by `s`, then then no difference as `func()` simply is reading the string.

If `func()` is `func(char *s)`, and attempts to modify the string pointed to by `s` [OP later reports this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60032415/what-is-the-difference-in-using-variable-as-function-argument-and-in-using-direc/60033350#comment106169602_60032415), then   `func(string)` is OK as `string` is a modifiable character array.  Yet `func("Any string")` is *undefined behavior* (UB).  [@John3136](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60032415/what-is-the-difference-in-using-variable-as-function-argument-and-in-using-direc/60033350#comment106169593_60032415)  [@William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60032415/what-is-the-difference-in-using-variable-as-function-argument-and-in-using-direc/60033350#comment106170617_60032415)  Code should not attempt to modify a *string literal*.  As OP reports the first works and the 2nd is "not working", this is the prime suspect.

For certainty, the definition of `func()` is needed as other explanations are possible.

Answer (score -2):

ok, so.... When you declare a "text string", it's type is:

```cpp
const char* const text = "text string";
```

Now you can copy that to a char buffer, so this is ok:

```cpp
char string[] = "Any string";
```

because 'string' in this context is a *copy* of the original text (with it's own memory). 
This however would not be ok:

```cpp
char* ptr = "Some Text";
```

The reason is that "Some Text" is constant, and you are asking to refer to it as some memory that can be changed. This would imply to me that your 'func' has the following prototype:

```cpp
void func(char* str);
```

Now in the above example, you could pass 'string' to it because the types match. You can't pass "Any String" though, because it's const. If however the prototype is:

```cpp
void func(const char* str);
```

Then there should be no issue.

Comment: The first point is not correct. In C, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2245983/5567382), the type of a string literal is `char []`, without any `const`. You can use it anywhere you would use a `char *`, but it's undefined behavior to modify the string.