# Why do C compilers make it so hard to get -Wwrite-strings warnings?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

Consider this C code:

```
void foo(char *);

void bar(void) {
    foo("");
}
```

When I compile that with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra` with GCC or Clang, or with `-Weverything` with Clang, it compiles without giving me any relevant warnings. If I add `-Wwrite-strings`, then GCC gives me this:

```
<source>:4:9: warning: passing argument 1 of 'foo' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
    4 |     foo("");
      |         ^~
<source>:1:10: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
    1 | void foo(char *);
      |          ^~~~~~
```

And clang gives me this:

```
<source>:4:9: warning: passing 'const char [1]' to parameter of type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    foo("");
        ^~
<source>:1:16: note: passing argument to parameter here
void foo(char *);
               ^
```

Lots of things seem wrong here to me:

- This seems like a pretty important warning not only to be off by default, but also to be off even with most of the ways that people enable warnings in practice.
- GCC's output refers to `-Wdiscarded-qualifiers`, but if I pass that instead of `-Wwrite-strings`, I don't get that warning.
- I thought `-Weverything` meant "literally every single warning the compiler knows about", but this seems to contradict that.
- If I compile the same code as C++ instead of as C, then both GCC and Clang give me the warning I want without needing any compiler flags at all. I'm not sure why there's a difference between the languages here, since AFAIK, both C and C++ have undefined behavior if you actually write to the string literal.

What's going on here? Why does this particular warning seem so buggy?

Comment: History and preferences seem likely, just as “-Wall” isn’t “all warnings”.

Comment: Compiling with `clang-cl` under Visual Studio 2019, with "Enable All Warnings" set *does* give the warning: **ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]** (as well as **no previous prototype for function 'bar' [-Wmissing-prototypes]**).

Comment: What does “Enable all Warnings” in VS *actually* translate to the compiler invocation? Seems to be including -Wwritable-strings.. each tool layer is separate.

Comment: @user2864740 I'm not sure - trying to figure out how to get the command line displayed. For the native MSVC compiler, it adds the `/Wall` switch. Also, MSVC gives an **error** with `/permissive-` (conformance mode) but not even a warning without it.

Comment: @user2864740 Well, according to the build log, the only "-W" switches passed to clang are `-Weverything` and  `-Wno-error`.

Comment: @adrianmole in Pascal it will not compile at all. but how is it relevant to the question?  C++ is not C

Comment: @P__J__ My previous comments were all  based on compilations with C++ compilers! Where did you get Pascal (and C) from?

Comment: @AdrianMole My question is about C.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Ah, OK! Gotcha.

Comment: @AdrianMole But good catch about C++: I just added a point about it to my list in the question.

Comment: The docs are clear what `-Wwrite-strings` do. There is no "write-strings warning", rather the warning you get is expected. You question seems to be targeted specifically to gcc developers. `why there's a difference between the languages here` I do not understand this question. C is not C++, the languages differ. There is the difference, because they are different languages.

Comment: @AdrianMole instead of Pascal you can put there any language - Ada, Python, PHP ..... It will be same relevant. I

Comment: @P__J__ Yeah - I got the point, eventually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C, string literals existed before `const` did. So C string literals were not const-qualified (although the results of attempting to write to them are not defined by the C standard). If string literals were made const-qualified, much old software would break due to type errors. The C committee has decided this change is not worthwhile.

The switch `-Wwrite-strings` is not really a warning switch, in spite of `-W`. It changes the language being compiled to a non-standard C in which string literals are const-qualified. [(There is a bug report that it is a mistake for GCC to categorize this as a warning switch.)](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61579) This explains why GCC shows a `-Wdiscarded-qualifier` when a string literal is assigned to a `char *`, and it also explains why `-Wdiscarded-qualifier` alone does not trigger these warnings—because without `-Wwrite-strings`, the string literal is not const-qualified, so no qualifier is being discarded by the assignment.

Presumably Clang’s `-Weverything` does not include `-Wwrite-strings` because, as noted above, it is not truly a warning option and because it changes the language to non-standard C.

Comment: "The switch `-Wwrite-strings` is not really a warning switch, in spite of `-W`. It changes the language being compiled to a non-standard C in which string literals are const-qualified." Yep, that's the key. Those two sentences explain everything I've noticed. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, re "In C, string literals existed before `const` did", was that K&R? Because `const` existed in C89, right?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: Right, `const` was not even a keyword in [K&R I](https://archive.org/details/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition/mode/2up) (see page 180), but in C89 it was.

Comment: There's actually GCC problem report about this: [Bug 61579 - -Wwrite-strings does not behave as a warning option](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61579)

Answer (score 2):

> This seems like a pretty important warning not only to be off by default, but also to be off even with most of the ways that people enable warnings in practice.

Well, the authors of gcc disagree with you, and they have explained why in the manual:

> > `-Wwrite-strings`
> >
> > When compiling C, give string constants the type `const char[length]` so that copying the address of one into a non-`const` `char *` pointer produces a warning. These warnings help you find at compile time code that can try to write into a string constant, but only if you have been very careful about using `const` in declarations and prototypes. Otherwise, it is just a nuisance. This is why we did not make `-Wall` request these warnings.

This also explains your second question:

> GCC's output refers to -Wdiscarded-qualifiers, but if I pass that instead of -Wwrite-strings, I don't get that warning.

Because without `-Wwrite-strings`, the string literal merely has type `char[]`, so no qualifier is being discarded.

(This also explains why the message mentions `-Wdiscarded-qualifiers` instead of `-Wwrite-strings`; the problem really is a discarded qualifier, and the warning code for that doesn't backtrack to tell you that the only reason there was a qualifier in the first place was because of a different option.  That would be awfully complicated.)

> I thought -Weverything meant "literally every single warning the compiler knows about", but this seems to contradict that.

Yes, that's what the clang manual claims that it does mean:

> > In addition to the traditional -W flags, one can enable all diagnostics by passing -Weverything. This works as expected with -Werror, and also includes the warnings from -pedantic.

Indeed, this has already been filed as a bug: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18801.  Apparently `-Weverything` did enable this warning in clang 3.4 and earlier, but there was a regression, or else an intentional change which was not documented.  Eric Postpischil's answer gives a plausible reason why it might have been intentional: it not only enables a warning but actually changes the language dialect.

> If I compile the same code as C++ instead of as C, then both GCC and Clang give me the warning I want without needing any compiler flags at all. I'm not sure why there's a difference between the languages here, since AFAIK, both C and C++ have undefined behavior if you actually write to the string literal.

In C++ (apparently since C++11) the type of a string literal actually is defined by the language as being `const char[]`, while  in standard C it has always been merely  a `char []` that you must not write to.  See [What is the type of string literals in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245664/what-is-the-type-of-string-literals-in-c-and-c)