# Can't write to a char* passed parameter function, it crashes

Tags: c, parameters, c-strings

I'm updating an old program and the function CleanStr() which should remove all tab characters and spaces from the start and ending of the string. The problem is that it crashes when I call strcpy() at the end, trying to modify the supplied parameter C string. The problem is not null termination of the supplied string, that's checked elsewhere and it's always valid.

Here is the code:

```c
bool IsEmptyChar(char tchar)
{
    if (tchar == 0x09 || tchar == 0x0D || tchar == 0x0A || tchar == ' ')
        return true;

    return false;
}

char* CleanStr(char* tstr)
{
    int len = strlen(tstr);

    if (len <= 0)
        return tstr;

    char tempstr[MAX_ST_SIZE];
    memset(tempstr, NULL, MAX_ST_SIZE);

    unsigned int pos1 = 0;
    unsigned int pos2 = len;

    // get starting pos
    while (IsEmptyChar(tstr[pos1]) && pos1 < MAX_ST_SIZE - 1)
        pos1++;

    // get final pos
    while ((IsEmptyChar(tstr[pos2]) || tstr[pos2] == NULL) && pos2 > 0)
        pos2--;

    // Parse string into limits 
    unsigned int a;
    for (a = pos1; a < pos2 + 1; a++)
        tempstr[a - pos1] = tstr[a];

    strcpy(tstr, tempstr); // This line makes program crash

    return tstr;
}
```

Comment: Please show us a [mre]. Until then we can only guess badly.

Comment: Your tstr is not writable but it is hard to tell why without seeing where it originates

Comment: On a couple of different notes, [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) can never return a negative value (which is why it returns an unsigned `size_t` value); `NULL` is a null *pointer* not a "null value" (which doesn't exist in C); You need to check the indexes *before* you use them (in for example `IsEmptyChar(tstr[pos1]) && pos1 < MAX_ST_SIZE - 1`); Your `IsEmptyChar` calls should be switched to [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace); And your "parse string into limits" loop could be replaced with a `memcpy` call.

Comment: I'd guess that you're passing a string literal to the `CleanStr()` function, which crashes trying to modify non-modifiable memory.  You should never try to modify a string literal.  It leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm not passing literals to cleanstr() just normal dinamically built char arrays (c strings)

Comment: NULL is defined as 0 in my C++

Comment: But you're programming in C, not C++. And in C++ the `NULL` macro is kept for backward compatibility with C mostly, you should be using `nullptr` for null pointers. And `0` for the integer value `0`, in both C and C++.

Comment: If the code is not being given a string literal, you definitely need to show us an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).  Without that, we can only speculate — it'll be hit'n'miss whether anyone guesses correctly.

Comment: I think I was passing a literal in 2 places, sorry, you were right guys

Comment: For consistency, you should change `if (tchar == 0x09 || tchar == 0x0D || tchar == 0x0A || tchar == ' ')` to use `0x20` in place of `' '` — or, much better, use `'\t'`, `'\r'`, `'\n'` in place of the three hex constants.  You really don't need to memorize the encodings for tab, carriage return, newline; just use the character constants.  Or even use the `isspace()` function from `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: Is there any way of determining if a char* contains a literal at runtime?

Comment: @Grunwaldt If your compiler supports it, you can enable the option `-Wwrite-strings` to make string literals const. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61430826/why-do-c-compilers-make-it-so-hard-to-get-wwrite-strings-warnings.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few small problems with the code that are corrected with the following changes and safeguards:

- `MAX_ST_SIZE` is defined for both the temp buffer within `CleanStr()` *and* the input buffer in main. `strcpy()` from within `CleanStr()` is arguably safer now.
- `get final pos` `while()` condition is updated to guard against the pathological condition of `pos2` becoming less than `pos1`.
- `NULL` was used improperly in 2 locations (especially if `NULL` is defined as `((void *)0)` for your platform).  `NULL` was replaced with a zero(0) in `memset()` and `'\0'` in `while()` of the `get final pos` codeblock.
- Constants in `IsEmptyChar()` are updated per community comments -- with which I agree.

Tested, runnable code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/EYKvx338h).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h> /* bool, true, false */

#define MAX_ST_SIZE 40

bool IsEmptyChar(char tchar)
{
    /* Updated constants: Best practice */
    if (tchar == '\t' || tchar == '\r' || tchar == '\n' || tchar == ' ')
        return true;

    return false;
}

char* CleanStr(char* tstr)
{
    int len = strlen(tstr);

    if (len <= 0)
        return tstr;

    char tempstr[MAX_ST_SIZE];
    memset(tempstr, 0, MAX_ST_SIZE);  /* Updated */

    unsigned int pos1 = 0;
    unsigned int pos2 = len;

    // get starting pos
    while (IsEmptyChar(tstr[pos1]) && pos1 < MAX_ST_SIZE - 1)
        pos1++;

    // get final pos
    while ((IsEmptyChar(tstr[pos2]) || tstr[pos2] == '\0') && pos2 > pos1) /* Updated */
        pos2--;

    // Parse string into limits 
    unsigned int a;
    for (a = pos1; a < pos2 + 1; a++)
        tempstr[a - pos1] = tstr[a];

    strcpy(tstr, tempstr); // This line (no longer) makes program crash

    return tstr;
}


int main()
{
char s1[MAX_ST_SIZE]={' ','\n','\t','\n','\r','H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d','\n','\t','\n','\r', ' '};
char s2[MAX_ST_SIZE]={' ','\n','\t','\n','\r', '\n','\t','\n','\r', ' '};
char *res = CleanStr(s1);

    printf("Res: %s\n", res);
    
    res = CleanStr(s2);
    printf("Res: %s\n", res);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Res: Hello World
Res:
```