# Copy from char * to char arrray

Tags: c, visual-c++

My character pointer points to some memorry say "Hello world" and i want to compare this with other pointer and later want to do strcpy. I sit possible to do with char *

```
char *A ="hello"
char *B ="";

strcmp(A,B); // this compares correctly because B points to diff string
strcpy(B,A); // will this statment copies the string alone or both will point to same memory
```

Comment: Well, you can easily check this.

Comment: The pointer "B" refers to a read-only memory location and therefore you will not be able to copy the string. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051347/in-c-can-i-initialize-a-string-in-a-pointer-declaration-the-same-way-i-can-init

Comment: `char *B` is read only, you have to `char B[6]` or `char *b = malloc(strlen(a) + 1)` in order to get space for copy

Comment: you have to first assign memory to B, by malloc(6); to get a new copy of a string

Comment: So what's the question?

Answer (score 5):

```
char *B ="";
```

This means that `B` is a pointer and you have pointed to the constant string `""`.

Copy the `A` string to the `B` with `strcpy(B,A);`

This means that you are copying the string of `A` to the memory which the `B` is pointing (and `B` is pointing to a constant string) so this will cause **undefined behaviour**

To avoid a such problem the B pointer should be pointed to a memory space for example you can point the B to a dynamic memory space allocated with malloc:

```
char *B = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
```

and you can make the size of the memory exactely the same of A string size with:

```
char *B = malloc((strlen(A)+1)*sizeof(char));
```

The +1 is for the null terminator character for the string

Another solution to avoid the problem: Define the B as an array of chars and not as a pointer:

```
char B[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

your code will compile successfully as strcpy needs destination and source char * as argument.

char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );

but you will get segmentation fault when you execute it...bcoz B points to no where first you have to allocate block of memory where B points at, by B=malloc(6);

```
char *A ="hello";
char *B;

B = malloc(6);

strcmp(A,B);
strcpy(B,A);
```

once you do this, yes strcpy will copy a total new string. A and B both will point to two different locations.