# In C, how can I convert a string to a character array?

Tags: c, string, argv

I have the passed argument `argv[1]` in my C program, and I want to convert that string into a character array. How may I do this?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char c [] = argv[1]; // This is what I want to do...
}
```

EDIT:

What I'm trying to do is get certain characters from `argv[1]` and check if they are numbers. So, ideally, I would do something like:

```
int a = argv[1][2]
```

But this just runs into another problem - how can I check the type of a variable in C?

Comment: What exactly is your goal here? You can already access `argv[1]` in the same way you can an array (`argv[1][0]`, `argv[1][1]`, ...).

Comment: Trick question!  A C string *is* a null-terminated character array.

Comment: @mootinator: A character pointer and a character array (the types) are not totally identical.

Comment: @Jefromi: How so? C doesn't do bounds-checking on array values.

Comment: @Christian Mann: See for example [C: differences between pointer and array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-pointer-and-array). One is a variable containing an address, one is not.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it already is a character array, NULL-terminated. You can simply choose to make another pointer to it, by saying `char *c = argv[1];`, or you can copy the entire string (null-terminator and all) into another array using the `strcpy(char *destination, char *source)`function http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/ like this:

```
char c[BUFFER]; //This has to be big enough to hold length + 1
strcpy(c, argv[1]);
```

Either approach is valid.

Comment: It is not already a character array. It is a pointer to a contiguous block of memory containing characters. There is a (subtle) difference, though they behave the same in many ways.

Answer (score 3):

You can treat `argv[1]` *as though* it were an array of `char` (i.e., you can subscript it as `argv[1][i]`).  You can pass it as an argument to any function that doesn't try to modify it (e.g., `printf`, `strtol`, `strchr`, etc.).  You cannot *write* to it, though, so if you need to modify the contents for any reason (either directly or through a function like `strtok` or `strcpy`), you'll have to create a local copy and manipulate that.

If you are using C89 or earlier, use this method:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *c = NULL;
  if (argc >= 2)
  {
    c = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
    strcpy(c, argv[1]);
  }
  /**
   * Do stuff with c
   */
  free(c);
  return 0;
}
```

If you are using C99, you can use a VLA:

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc < 2)
    return 0;

  size_t len = strlen(argv[1]);
  char c[len+1];
  strcpy(c, argv[1]);
  /**
   * do stuff with c
   */
  return 0;
}
```

Just remember a few things:

1. The *type* of `argv` is `char **`, *not* `char *[N]`; similarly, the type of `argv[i]` is `char *`, not `char [M]`.  In most circumstances it doesn't matter; you can use a subscript operator on a pointer *as though* it were an array (array subscripting is *defined* in terms of pointer arithmetic), but remember that pointers and arrays **are not the same thing** and are not always interchangeable;
2. The *value* of `argv[argc]` is always `NULL`;
3. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators or is a string literal being used as an initializer in a declaration, an *expression* of array type is converted ("decays") from "N-element array of T" to "pointer to T", and the *value* of the expression is the location of the first element;
4. C doesn't have a string data type as such; strings are *represented* as 0-terminated sequences of `char`.  String literals such as `"hello"` are stored in such a way that they exist over the lifetime of the program, and you can access them via a pointer value; attempting to modify them results in undefined behavior (i.e., don't do that).

Answer (score 1):

`argv[1][2]` is of type `char`, always (<pedantry>accessing it causes undefined behavior if there are less than two arguments or if the length of the second argument is less than two - so its questionable whether it has a type in those cases</pedantry>). The character itself may represent a number however, and to check that, use `isdigit()` from header `<ctypes.h>`

```
#include <ctypes.h>
...
if (argc > 1) {
  int digits = 0;
  for (int i = 0, len = strlen(argv[1]); i < len; ++i)
    if (isdigit(argv[1][i]))
      digits++;
  printf("Digits in %s: %d\n", argv[1], digits);
}
```

Comment: <pedantry>NOTHING has a true "type" in C -- it's all you access it. Watch: `char c; int i; c = 'A'; i = c; //i is now 65`. Sheesh, I could access a pointer value as an integer and it would let me. Remember, it's just binary.</pedantry>

Comment: @Christian: Your comment is not pedantic but incorrect. Objects do have types in C, and except for a few specific cases defined in the standard, accessing an object through a pointer of different type is undefined behavior. BTW your comment has nothing to do with accessing as different types, only with implicit conversion from int to char and then char to int, which are *value* conversions, not reinterpretations of binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, argv[1] is already a character array.  There really isn't such a thing as a "string" in standard C.

What do you want to do with it?  Do you just want a copy of it?  In that case, you'd need to malloc some space for a new character array and then use "strcpy" to copy from argv[1] into your character array.

Comment: No. `argv[1]` is a character pointer, not a character array. They may behave the same in many cases, but there are differences.

Comment: The correct way to state this is that `argv[1]` **points to the first char of a char array**.