# C++ - Is an array a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C: differences between pointer and array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-pointer-and-array)

Is an `array` in `C++` a `pointer`? Can you clarify this?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is not **exact** duplicate as it asks for C++ and there is more to it in C++ than in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array name itself without any index is a pointer.

```
int a[10];
printf("%d\n",*a); // will print first value
printf("%d\n",*(a+1) ); // will print second value
```

Comment: No, it's not, but it auto-converts to one. This question is tagged to C++, C++ has template and it sure matters when substituting one.

Comment: `sizeof array` is the size of the array, not the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 8):

No. But it can decay to a pointer whenever you need it.

```
void foo1(char * c) {
}


int main() {
  char Foo[32];
  foo1(Foo); // Foo decays to a pointer
  char * s = Foo; // Foo decays to a pointer which is assigned to s
}
```