# C allocated pointers? What's this?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, char

I have the below code.

```
char a[] = "abcde";
char *b = "fghij";
char *c = malloc(6);
char *d = c;
c = "klmno";
```

And the exercise states:

> Draw a picture of the data structures a, b, c and d(with content),
>   where you can see what has been allocated and use arrows to show how
>   pointers are set.

My solution is:

```
      ____________
a -> |a|b|c|d|e|\0|
      ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
      ____________
b -> |f|g|h|i|j|\0|
      ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
      ____________
c -> |k|l|m|n|o|\0|
      ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
      ___________
d -> | | | | | | |
      ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
```

However my solution did not get accepted and the response was "*allocated memory for a pointer to b, c, d but not a*". Can someone explain me what this means?

Comment: It's unclear from your question what was your answer and what was wrong with it. Please try to rephrase it to make it more understandable.

Comment: @karlphillip, c wasn't filled, it was reassigned.

Comment: No, the contents of `c` are **not** copied to `d`.

Comment: This is kind of a trick question, and I would say you passed it. In practice when a program is running, there is no difference between, for example, `a` and `b`. Maybe you could have said that "abcde" was on the stack, but that's about it.

Comment: @David strictly speaking we do copy the contents. It's just that pointers have some address as content.

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/); once you're there, read the other sections too :)

Comment: Come to think of it, the data pointed to by `d` will be random, as it points to uninitialized memory.

Comment: @Pithikos No, `d = c` assigns the pointer, the contents are not copied.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a slightly cryptic response, but I guess the complaint is that the array `a` doesn't *point* to that data; it *contains* the data.

So this might be what is required (without the pointer arrow):

```
    ____________
a  |a|b|c|d|e|\0|
    ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
```

The name of an array can be used as a pointer, but it still has a subtly different meaning.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. However isn't array essentially just a pointer to the first element?

Comment: The name of an array points to the very first element of that array. It's a pointer in this sense.

Comment: It looks like they wanted picture like [this](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html).

Comment: @Pithikos: No, it's not.  The array `a` is just the collection of 6 `char`s.  In some circumstances `a` will evaluate to a pointer to the first character, but that's not the same thing as saying that `a` *is* a pointer (which it is not).

Comment: @caf "collection of char" is just an abstract notion. I agree that an array is not the pointer data structure. However it has an address as content just as a pointer. In that way you can say it's a pointer. It's just that we don't mean the data structure pointer in this case.

Comment: @Pithikos: A collection of 6 chars is no more abstract than a single char.  The content of the array is the 6 chars that make it up; no more, no less.

Comment: The real explanation is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-pointer-and-array a still points to the data. The data is just allocated on the stack and copied.

Comment: @Pithikos Why do you ask the question here if you already appear to know all the answers?

Answer (score 7):

I would draw them like this:

```
      ____________
     |a|b|c|d|e|\0|
      ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
           a
      ____________
b -> |f|g|h|i|j|\0|
      ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
      ____________
c -> |k|l|m|n|o|\0|
      ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
      _____________
d -> |g|a|r|b|a|g|e|
      ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
```

Notice how the `a` is below the whole array, not next to an arrow. This is to emphasize that `a` is a whole array that contains the string itself, not just a pointer. This shows that you realise the difference between an *array* and a *pointer*.

Comment: @Andrey: no, it's not. There's a distinct difference between an array and a pointer. Although array identifiers decay to a pointer in certain contexts, that doesn't make them pointers. Try `sizeof(a)` and `sizeof(b)` and see the difference for yourself.

Comment: Yes, you're right at this point. But actually it doesn't really matter in here, I think.

Comment: You have `d` pointing to 7 bytes of garbage; it should only be 6. :)

Answer (score 1):

Content of memory pointing by `d` is not determined actually. It must be contain some garbage which comes from `malloc()` on `c`

Answer (score 1):

I would even try to distinguish where the data pointed to lives.

```
  ____________
a|a|b|c|d|e|\0| (in data segment or on stack)
  ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
  _____      ____________
b|ptr->| -> |f|g|h|i|j|\0| (in rodata)
  ¨¨¨¨¨      ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
  _____      ____________
c|ptr->| -> |k|l|m|n|o|\0| (in rodata)
  ¨¨¨¨¨      ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
  _____      ___________
d|ptr->| -> |X|X|X|X|X|X| (on heap)
  ¨¨¨¨¨      ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are pretty much right:

```
    char a[] = "abcde";
    printf("a[]: [%s] length:%d\n", a, strlen(a));

    char* b = "fghij";
    printf("*b: [%s] length:%d\n", b, strlen(b));

    char* c = (char*)malloc(6);
    char* d = c;

    c = "klmno";
    printf("*d = c: d is [%s] length:%d\n", d, strlen(d));
    printf("*d = c: c is [%s] length:%d\n", c, strlen(c));
```

**Outputs:**

```
a[]: [abcde] length:5
*b: [fghij] length:5
*d = c: d is [] length:0
*d = c: c is [klmno] length:5
```

**Note:** Even though `strlen()` searches for the `NULL` character to be able to iterate on an array of strings and count characters, the ocurrence of `NULL` itself is not added to the final sum, that's why it reports 5 characters instead of 6.

As for your answer not being accepted, there is probably some other form of representation your teacher was expecting you to do for array `a`, you might be interested to talk to your colleagues about it, but I don't think is fair to state that you gave a wrong answer.