# Difference of sizeof between char* x and char x[]

Tags: c, char, sizeof

I know some difference between char* and char[].
`char x[] = "xxxx"` 
Is an array of chars; 
`char *y = "xxxx"` 
is a pointer to the literal (const) string;
And `x[4]=='\0'`, and `*(y+4) == '\0'` too.
So why `sizeof(x)==5` and `sizeof(y)==4`?

Comment: define x as char x[] = "xxxxxxxx" instead. THen ask yourself the same question...Hint: terminating '\0'

Comment: @MitchWheat I think he understands that x has five characters. The issue is that y is a pointer so sizeof(y) = 4 (bytes).

Comment: @eli: yes, I know that. But I didn't want to give a direct answer. Teach a man to fish and all that....

Comment: @MitchWheat the terminating '\0' has nothing to do with his question though. He knows about the terminating '\0', he's using that to show that there are five characters so the size should be 5. If you had said define y as char *y = "xxxxxxxx" instead, then he would've seen the size stayed constant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C: differences between pointer and array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-pointer-and-array) and many others...

Comment: Yes, I get to know x and y are both terminating '\0',and strlen(x)==strlen(y)==4, but I made a mistake sizeof(char*) will be always be 4...

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sizeof an array type is the size the array takes up. Same as `sizeof("xxxx")`.

The sizeof a pointer type is the size the pointer itself takes up. Same as `sizeof(char*)`.

Answer (score 10):

`char x[] = "xxxx"` is an array of size 5 containing x x x x and \0.

`char *y = "xxxx"` is a pointer to a string. It's length is 4 bytes, because that is the length of the pointer, not the string.

Answer (score 4):

`x` is really `"xxxx\0"`. The nul terminator at the end of the string gives the array five bytes.

However, `sizeof(y)` is asking for the size of a pointer, which happens to be four bytes in your case. What `y` is pointing to is of no consequence to the `sizeof()`.

Answer (score 0):

For `char *x`, x is a pointer, which means you can change the pointed-to position by `x++`, `x+=2`, etc. 
`char x[]` is an array, which is a constant pointer so you cannot do x++