# C basics: comparing "*char" and "char[x]" for string creation

Tags: c, string

A pretty basic C question.  Why do the following two commands result in the creation of strings that have different sizes?

As you can see below, method 1 creates a string with size 8 bytes and method 2 creates a string with size 5 bytes.

Am confused as to why method 1 is creating a string of size 8 bytes...

(I've already seen these posts: [Difference of sizeof between char* x and char x[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560523/difference-of-sizeof-between-char-x-and-char-x) and [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c?lq=1).  Unless I had a reading-comprehension-fail, it doesn't really address why method 1 creates a string of size 8 bytes...  According to the responses, it would seem that method 1 should be creating a pointer of size 4 bytes.)

Method 1:

```
char *string = "ABCD";
```

Method 2:

```
char string2[5] = "ABCD";
```

For example, when I run the following program, I get the output shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *string = "ABCD";

  printf("Based on \"char *string = \"ABCD\":\n");
  printf("Size of string: %ld\n",sizeof(string));
  printf("Size of each element of string: %ld\n",sizeof(string[0]));
  printf("String: %s\n\n", string);

  char string2[5] = "ABCD\0";

  printf("Based on \"char string2[5] = \"ABCD\":\n");
  printf("Size of string: %ld\n",sizeof(string2));
  printf("Size of each element of string: %ld\n",sizeof(string2[0]));
  printf("String: %s\n\n", string2);

  return 0;
}
```

Output of the above program:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char \*s in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Comment: another possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538210/sizeof-a-pointer

Comment: Also, for `char string3[] = "ABCDE";` (no size declared) `sizeof(string3) == 6` (5 letters + the nul)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because in this line `char *string = "ABCD";` you are declaring a pointer to char which a size of 8 bytes where as in this line `char string2[5] = "ABCD";` you are declaring an array of 5 chars and since a `char` is 1 byte long and `1 * 5 == 5 bytes` then the size of `string2` will be 5 bytes

Comment: This may be an inane question but can you elaborate as to why a pointer to char has a size that's 8 times larger than the type it's pointing to (or 2x larger if you consider the four characters in ABCD, i.e., excluding /0)?   (I understand why `char string2[5] = "ABCD"` results has a size of 5 bytes.  )

Comment: because a pointer stores memory address not characters and memory addresses are usually 8 bytes

Comment: I understand now, thanks.  I think I was confused because some of the responses in the other threads implied that pointers took up only 4 bytes of memory, which is indeed the case in 32-bit but not for 64-bit (and I'm obv running the latter).

Answer (score 0):

A char only has to hold an ASCII value, which is a very small range of numbers, so they only take up 1 byte each.

A char* is a pointer to an address in memory, which is a much larger range of numbers, hence more bytes are required to store it.  A pointer on a 32-bit system takes up 4 bytes, and on a 64-bit system, takes up 8 bytes.

I take it you're running on a 64-bit system?  I think that's why it's 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you declare a variable that is a pointer to a `char`. So, when you take its size with `sizeof`, you get the size of the pointer (not the size of the thing it's pointing at), which is 8 bytes on a 64-bit platform.

In the second example, you declare a variable that is an array of `char`. In C, the `sizeof` an array does as you would expect - it returns the size of the array in bytes, which in this case is `5 * sizeof(char)` (since you declared a 5 character array), which is 5 (since `sizeof(char) = 1`).

In either case, using `sizeof` is generally not the correct way to measure the length of a string - you should be using [strlen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) instead. This will correctly handle cases where the string terminator character `NUL` appears somewhere other than at the end of the `char` array.