# Why Segmentation fault in following code?

Tags: c

I read this on wikipedia

```
    int main(void)
 {

    char *s = "hello world";
    *s = 'H';

 }
```

When the program containing this code is compiled, the string "hello world" is placed in the section of the program executable file marked as read-only; when loaded, the operating system places it with other strings and constant data in a read-only segment of memory. When executed, a variable, s, is set to point to the string's location, and an attempt is made to write an H character through the variable into the memory, causing a segmentation fault**

i don't know why the string is placed in read only segment.please someone could explain this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C: differences between pointer and array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-pointer-and-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String literals are stored in read-only memory, that's just how it works. Your code uses a pointer initialized to point at the memory where a string literal is stored, and thus you can't validly modify that memory.

To get a string in modifiable memory, do this:

```
char s[] = "hello world";
```

then you're fine, since now you're just using the constant string to initialize a non-constant array.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Doh. I should have known that was too simply put. Rewritten, and thanks.

Comment: @unwind there would be no *question* if string literals were `const char*`: the code just wouldn't compile (that's why I downvoted -- and I'm removing the downvote as you corrected it). That said, in all the answers so far there's no attempt to explain the *purpose* of moving string literals to read-only sections. (It's unclear whether the question asks for the purpose or "that's just how it works" is enough).

Answer (score 3):

There is a big difference between:

```
char * s = "Hello world";
```

and

```
char s[] = "Hello world";
```

In the first case, `s` is a pointer to something that you can't change. It's stored in read-only memory (typically, in the code section of your application).

In the latter case, you allocate an array in read-write memory (typically plain RAM), that you can modify.

Comment: In the first case I also expect the compiler issuing a warning about assigning a const to non-const or something.

Answer (score 2):

- When you do: `char *s = "hello world";` then `s` is *a pointer that points to a memory* that is in the **code part**, so you **can't** change it.
- When you do: `char s[] = "Hello World";` then `s` is *an array of chars*
  that are on the **stack**, so you **can** change it.

If you don't want the string to be changed during the program, it is better to do: `char
   const *s = ....;`. Then, when you try to change the string, your program **will not crash with segmentation fault**, it will arise a **compiler error** (which is much better).

Answer (score 0):

first have a good understanding of pointers, I will give u a short demo:

First let us analyze your code line by line. Lets start from main onwards

char *s = "Some_string";

first of all, you are declaring a pointer to a char variable, now *s is a address in memory, and C will kick you if you try to change its memory value, thats illegal, so u better declare a character array, then assign s to its address, then change s.

Hope you get, it. For further reference and detailed understanding, refer KN King: C programming A Modern Approach

Answer (score 0):

Per the language definition, string literals have to be stored in such a way that their lifetime extends over the lifetime of the program, and that they are visible over the entire program.

Exactly what this means in terms of *where* the string gets stored is **up to the implementation**; the language definition does not mandate that string literals are stored in read-only memory, and not all implementations do so.  It only says that attempting to modify the contents of a string literal results in undefined behavior, meaning the implementation is free to do whatever it wants.