# C : why does only some literal strings crash my program?

Tags: c, string

I tried the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char s1[] = "Global String";
char *s2 = "Another Global String";

main()
{
    char s3[] = "Local String" ;
    char *s4 = "Another Local String" ;

    strcpy( s1, "New str" );
    strcpy( s2, "New str" ); // causes seg fault
    strcpy( s3, "New str" );
    strcpy( s4, "New str" ); // causes seg fault
}
```

`s2` and `s4` cause segmentation fault, presumably because they are stored in read-only data segment.  How come the literal strings pointed by `s1` and `s3` don't crash?  This is on Ubuntu.

Strangely, `s1`, `s2`, `s3` and `s4` can all be modified and no crash occurs when compiled with gcc on cygwin.  Why is this?

Comment: See [**differences between char pointer and array**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array)

Comment: Because pointers are not arrays and string **constants** are **constant** (what a surprise, really.)

Comment: why does work with cygwin?

Comment: @user2460477 It doesn't. It **seems** to work.

Comment: Guys :-), within 60 seconds of posting my question, I had 4 answers, none of which answered my question fully and then it is marked duplicate and I dont have the full answer (cygwin part).  Possibly part of it was duplicate !!

Comment: @user2460477 hey don't worry. Post a new question. This time emphasizing the `cygwin` issue... like this works in cygwin why not in gcc?

Comment: @user2460477 Attempting to modify the contents of a string literal results in undefined behaviour.  The C standard doesn't specify what happens here - compiler vendors are free to implement whatever is convenient.  Both crashing and appearing to work are acceptable examples of undefined behaviour.  You've been unlucky that cygwin appeared to work with this incorrect code.

Comment: @simonc: Thanks.  I was trying to find form the net if this is due to specifics of Windows executable (does it have a readonly data section?).  Anyway, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char s1[] = "Global String";
```

reserves space for a writable buffer that contains *a copy of* the string literal.

```
char *s2 = "Another Global String";
```

declares a pointer to a read-only buffer containing the string literal.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `char *s2 = "Another Global String";`, `s2` is a pointer that points to a string constant, and by doing `strcpy( s2, "New str" );` you are trying to write on read only memory, that is illegal. For the same reason `strcpy( s4, "New str" );` is not valid.

`char s3[] = "Local String" ;` makes `s3` an array with the same length as the string constant (+1 for the trailing NULL). The string will be copied into that array, which you are free to modify.

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy` uses the memory that is prepared for it. If you have a static string, it may be in an non writable memory location, so if you copy a new string to it, it rightfully crashes.

You have to reserve memory first or use `strdup`.