# how to understand char * ch="123"?

Tags: c++, char

How should I understand `char * ch="123"`?

`'1'` is a `char`, so I can use:

```
char x = '1';
char *pt = &x;
```

But how do I understand `char *pt="123"`? Why can the `char *pt` point to string?

Is `pt`'s value the first address value for `"123"`? If so, how do I get the length for the string pointed to by `pt`?

Comment: Yes, this is illogical and horrible.  Not your question - the throwback C-style strings with null-terminators.  +1 for identifying the illogic of a pointer to a char actually pointing at more than one char.

Comment: @MartinJames: this is not C-style string specific, any pointer has this feature...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Not every pointer has the feature that it can address characters in a string literal. There are several aspects to this question (at least if you want to answer it comprehensively), and some of it is just about pointers, but some is about C's weird treatment of "strings"

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Only pointers to variable size data structures have this issue. Even then, that's only if you consider "this issue" being unable to know the size of a data structure from merely it's type and a pointer. You could, for example, define a "string" as the length of the string and then that many bytes of character data, which would sidestep all the awful issues that come from null termination.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That is actually a really good question, and it is the consequence of several oddities in the C language:

**1**: A pointer to a char (`char*`) can of course also point to a specific char in an array of chars. That is what pointer arithmetic relies on:

```
// create an array of three chars
char arr[3] = { 'a', 'b', 'c'};
// point to the first char in the array
char* ptr = &arr[0]
// point to the third char in the array
char* ptr = &arr[2]
```

**2**: A string literal (`"foo"`) is actually not a *string* as such, but simply an array of chars, followed by a null byte. (So `"foo"` is actually equivalent to the array `{'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'}`)

**3**: In C, arrays "decay" into pointers to the first element. (This is why many people incorrectly says that "there is no difference between arrays and pointers in C"). That is, when you try to assign an array to a pointer object, it sets the pointer to point to the first element of the array. So given the array `arr` declared above, you can do `char* ptr = arr`, and it means the same as `char* ptr = &arr[0]`.

**4**: In every other case, syntax like this would make the pointer point to an rvalue (loosely speaking, a temporary object, which you can't take the address of), which is generally illegal. (You can't do `int* ptr = &42`). But when you define a string literal (such as `"foo"`), it does not create an rvalue. Instead, it creates the char array *with static storage*. You're creating a static object, which is created when the program is loaded, and of course a pointer can safely point to *that*.

**5**: String literals are actually required to be marked as `const` (because they are static and read-only), but because early versions of C did not have the `const` keyword, you are allowed to omit the `const` specifier (at least prior to C++11), to avoid breaking old code (but you still have to treat the variable as read-only).

So `char* ch = "123"` really means:

1. write the char array `{'1', '2', '3', '\0'}` into the static section of the executable (so that when the program is loaded into memory, this variable is created in a read-only section of memory)
2. when this line of code is executed, create a pointer which points to the first element of this array

As a bonus fun fact, this differs from `char ch[] = "123";`, which instead means

1. write the char array `{'1', '2', '3', '\0'}` into the static section of the executable (so that when the program is loaded into memory, this variable is created in a read-only section of memory)
2. when this line of code is executed, create an array on the stack which contains a copy of this statically allocated array.

Comment: why int *pt={1,2,3} can't work but int pt[]={1,2,3} can work? can you help this?

Comment: @jiafu `{1,2,3}` can be used to initialize an array, but it *is* not an array. So in the second case, you use it to create an array named `pt`, containing those three numbers. But in the first case, you try to create a pointer to something that is not an object. That is where string literals are treated specially (see point #4 above) because it actually *creates* the array, which the syntax `{1,2,3}` does not do

Comment: Since C++11, you are no longer allowed to omit the `const`.

Comment: Awesome answer: but maybe mention or stress that a `const` will make the code much much better?

Comment: @MikeSeymour good point, I added a note mentioning this. Thanks.

Comment: @Yakk I feel like my answer is already fairly cluttered, so I'd rather not add more information unless it relates directly to the question. (Note that as Mike Seymour mentions above, in C++11 you are *required* to use `const` anyway, so it no longer matters that it subjectively improves the code. You just have to do it. And the question isn't about best practices, but simply what the statement *means*. (But you are of course right, you *should* use `const`)

Comment: This is a great answer.  I've been programming in C for a while, and feel that I learned something.

Answer (score 7):

`char* ptr = "123";` is compatible and almost equivalent to `char ptr[] = { '1', '2', '3', '\0' };` (see http://ideone.com/rFOk3R).

In C a pointer can point to one value or an array of contiguous values. C++ inherited this.
So a string is just an array of character (`char`) ended by a `'\0'`. And a pointer to `char` can point to an array of `char`.

The length is given by the number of character between the begining and the terminal `'\0'`. Exemple of C `strlen` giving you the length of the string:

```
size_t strlen(const char * str)
{
    const char *s;
    for (s = str; *s; ++s) {}
    return(s - str);
}
```

An yes it fails horribly if there is no `'\0'` at the end.

Comment: `char* ptr = "123";` is NOT `char* ptr = { '1', '2', '3', '\0' };`

Comment: I think you meant to say: `it fails horribly if there is no '\0' at the end.5]È╦³û§E;‼∟█«2 ÜP¯@x6²↕I2÷×}I▄P`

Comment: if so, char *pt1="123", char pt2[]="123", is pt2 is same with pt1?

Comment: @BЈовић Yep it is `char ptr[] = { '1', '2', '3', '\0' };`, which is compatible to char. I'm going to clarify.

Comment: thanks,what's more, why int *pt={1,2,3} can't work but int pt[]={1,2,3} can work? can you help this?

Comment: `char* ptr` and `char ptr[]` are not equivalent. In both cases, you can modify the values pointed by ptr. Guess what may happen if you modify the pointer to non-const char pointing to const char array :)  Something like this : http://ideone.com/i37oMP

Comment: @BЈовић Hence the "almost" ;) I used `const char*` in my example. But I think the compiler with warning disable do not even complain if you do not put the `const`... And in my memories, there was an option in gcc to set the string literal in a modifiable zone, hence allowing the modification without a crash.

Answer (score 5):

A string literal is an array of N `const char` where N is the length of the literal including the implicit NUL terminator. It has static storage duration and it's implementation defined where it is stored. From here on, it's the same a with a normal array - it decays to a pointer to its first character - that's a `const char*`. What you have there is not legal (not anymore since onset of C++11 standard) in C++, it should be `const char* ch = "123";`.

You can get the length of a literal with `sizeof` operator. Once it decays to a pointer, though, you need to iterate through it and find the terminator (that's what `strlen` function does).

So, with a `const char* ch;` you get a pointer to a constant character type that can point to  a single character, or to the start of an array of characters (or anywhere between the start and the end). The array can be dynamically, autimatically or statically allocated and can be mutable or not.

In something like `char ch[] = "text";` you have an **array** of characters. This is syntatic sugar for a normal array initializer (as in `char ch[] = {'t','e','x','t','\0'};` but note that the literal will still be loaded at the start of the program). What hapens here is:

- an array with automatic storage duration is allocated
- its size is deduced from the size of the literal by the compiler
- the contents of the literal are *copied* to the array

As a result, you have a region of storage that you can use at will (unlike literals, which must not be written into).

Comment: if so, char *pt1="123", char pt2[]="123", is pt2 is same with pt1?

Comment: @jiafu No, it's not. I'll expand on that in the answer, hang on.

Answer (score 3):

### A pointer to an array?

A pointer points to only one memory address. The phrase that a pointer points to an array is only used in a loose sense---a pointer cannot really store multiple addresses at the same time.

In your example, `char *ch="123"`, the pointer `ch` is really pointing to the first byte only. You can write code like the following, and it will make perfect sense:

```
char *ch = new char [1024];
sprintf (ch, "Hello");    
delete [] ch;

char x = '1';
ch = &x;
```

Please note the use of the pointer `ch` to point to both the memory allocated by `new char [1024]` line as well as the address of the variable `x`, while still being the same pointer type.

### C-style strings are null terminated

Strings in C used to be null terminated, i.e., a special `'\0'` was added to the end of the string and assumed to be there for all `char *` based functions (such as `strlen` and `printf`) This way, you can determine the length of the string by starting at the first byte and continue till you find the byte containing `0x00`.

A verbose, sample implementation of an`strlen` style function would be

```
int my_strlen (const char *startAddress)
{
  int count = 0;
  char *ptr = startAddress;
  while (*ptr != 0)
  {
     ++count;
     ++ptr;
  }

  return count;
}
```

Comment: if so, char *pt1="123", char pt2[]="123", is pt2 same with pt1?

Comment: **Almost** same, but not exactly the same. If you replace `char *ch` with `char ch[]` in my first example, the later assignment `ch = &x` will fail. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array

Answer (score 3):

There are no strings in C, but there are pointers to characters.
`*pt` is indeed not pointing to a string, but to a single characters (the `'1'`).
However, some functions take `char*` as argument assume that the byte on the address following the address that their argument points to, is set to `0` if they are not to operate on it.

In your example, if you tried using `pt` on a function which expects a "null terminated string" (basically, which expects that it will encounter a byte with a value of `0` when it should stop processing data) you will run into a segmentation fault, as `x='1'` gives `x`  the ascii value of the `1` character, but nothing more, whereas `char* pt="123"` gives pt the value of the address of `1`, but also puts into that memory, the bytes containing ascii values of `1`, `2`,`3` followed by a byte with a value of `0` (zero).

So the memory (in a 8 bit machine) may look like this:

Address  = Content (`0x31` is the Ascii code for the character 1 (one))

```
0xa0 = 0x31
0xa1 = 0x32
0xa2 = 0x33
0xa3 = 0x00
```

Let's suppose that you in the same machine `char* otherString = malloc(4)`,suppose that `malloc` returns a value of `0xb0`, which is now the value of `otherString`, and we wanted to copy our "`pt`" (which would have a value of `0xa0`) into `otherString`, the `strcpy` call would look like so:

```
strcpy( otherString, pt );
```

The same as

```
strcpy( 0xb0, 0x0a );
```

`strcpy` would then take the value of address `0xa0` and copy it into `0xb0`, it would increment it's pointers to "`pt`" to `0xa1`, check if `0xa1` is zero, if it is not zero, it would increment it's pointer to "`otherString`" and copy `0xa1` into `0xb1`, and so on, until it's "`pt`" pointer is `0xa3`, in this case, it will return as it detected that the end of the "string" has been reached.

This is of cause, not 100% how it goes on, and it could be implemented in many different ways.

Here is one http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.18/strcpy_8c_source.html

Answer (score 2):

```
char* pt = "123"; does two things:
```

1. creates the string literal "123" in ROM (this is usually in .text section)
 2. creates a `char*` which is assigned the beginning of memory location where the string is located.

because of this operations `like pt[1] = '2';` are illegal as you would be attempting to write  to ROM memory.

But you can assign the pointer to some other memory location without any problems.

Comment: if so, char *pt1="123", char pt2[]="123", is pt2 is same with pt1?

Comment: no it isn't char p2[] ="123"; has a different effect. The string literal "123" is still created in ROM but it is also copied to the stack and p2 point at the stack copy. So p2[0] = '1' is legal.

Comment: thanks,what's more, why int *pt={1,2,3} can't work but int pt[]={1,2,3} can work? can you help this?

Comment: for *pt={1,2,3},*pt points to a location in ROM while for pt[]={1,2,3}, pt points to a location on the stack (where you can write)