# char *array and char array[]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

if I write this

```
 char *array = "One good thing about music";
```

I actually create an array? I mean it's the same like this?

```
char array[] = {"One", "good", "thing", "about", "music"};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c

Comment: The edits made make the code faulty, or at least flawed. TIn the second example, `array` is an array of *characters*, that is initialized with *pointers* to characters. If an array of strings is wanted, then the declaration should be `char *array[] = { ... }`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The declaration and initialization

```
char *array = "One good thing about music";
```

declares a pointer `array` and make it point to a (read-only) array of 27 characters, including the terminating null-character.

The declaration and initialization

```
char array[] = "One, good, thing, about, music";
```

declares an array of characters, containing 31 characters.

And yes, the size of the arrays is 31, as it includes the terminating `'\0'` character.

---

Laid out in memory, it will be something like this for the first:

```
+-------+     +------------------------------+
| array | --> | "One good thing about music" |
+-------+     +------------------------------+
```

And like this for the second:

```
+------------------------------+
| "One good thing about music" |
+------------------------------+
```

---

Arrays decays to pointers to the first element of an array. If you have an array like

```
char array[] = "One, good, thing, about, music";
```

then using plain `array` when a pointer is expected, it's the same as `&array[0]`.

That mean that when you, for example, pass an array as an argument to a function it will be passed as a pointer.

Pointers and arrays are *almost* interchangeable. You can not, for example, use `sizeof(pointer)` because that returns the size of the actual pointer and not what it points to. Also when you do e.g. `&pointer` you get the address of the pointer, but `&array` returns a pointer to the array. It should be noted that `&array` is *very* different from `array` (or its equivalent `&array[0]`). While both `&array` and `&array[0]` point to the same location, the types are different. Using the array above, `&array` is of type `char (*)[31]`, while `&array[0]` is of type `char *`.

---

For more fun: As many knows, it's possible to use array indexing when accessing a pointer. But because arrays decays to pointers it's possible to use some pointer arithmetic with arrays.

For example:

```
char array[] = "Foobar";  /* Declare an array of 7 characters */
```

With the above, you can access the fourth element (the `'b`' character) using either

```
array[3]
```

or

```
*(array + 3)
```

And because addition is [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutativity), the last can also be expressed as

```
*(3 + array)
```

which leads to the fun syntax

```
3[array]
```

Comment: In the 2nd command, can use the `array` as a pointer to that array?

Comment: @Nat95 Updated my answer with another paragraph.

Comment: `&array`is a pointer to the array, not to the first element, which would be `&array[0]`.

Comment: You forgot the commas in the char* string literal sample.

Comment: I think this answer needs to be updated to keep up with changes to the original question!

Comment: @DrEval The problem is that the edit made was flawed and would lead to wrong behavior. I think the OP didn't mean to make it look like that, but to make it like in my answer (`char array[] = "..."`). Otherwise that would not make much sense and the two definitions would be vastly more different.

Answer (score 10):

No, you're creating an array, but there's a big difference:

```
char *string = "Some CONSTANT string";
printf("%c\n", string[1]);//prints o
string[1] = 'v';//INVALID!!
```

The array is created in a *read only* part of memory, so you can't edit the value through the pointer, whereas:

```
char string[] = "Some string";
```

creates the same, read only, constant string, and *copies* it to the stack array. That's why:

```
string[1] = 'v';
```

Is valid in the latter case.
If you write:

```
char string[] = {"some", " string"};
```

the compiler should complain, because you're constructing an array of char arrays (or char pointers), and assigning it to an array of chars. Those types don't match up. Either write:

```
char string[] = {'s','o','m', 'e', ' ', 's', 't','r','i','n','g', '\0'};
//this is a bit silly, because it's the same as char string[] = "some string";
//or
char *string[] = {"some", " string"};//array of pointers to CONSTANT strings
//or
char string[][10] = {"some", " string"};
```

Where the last version gives you an array of strings (arrays of chars) that you actually *can* edit...

Answer (score 3):

It's very similar to

```
char array[] = {'O', 'n', 'e', ' ', /*etc*/ ' ', 'm', 'u', 's', 'i', 'c', '\0'};
```

but gives you read-only memory.

For a discussion of the difference between a `char[]` and a `char *`, see [comp.lang.c FAQ 1.32](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html).

Comment: It means that if you try to write to it (e.g. `array[0] = 'X'`) you get undefined behaviour (normally a segmentation fault).

Answer (score 2):

No. Actually it's the "same" as

```
char array[] = {'O', 'n', 'e', ..... 'i','c','\0');
```

Every character is a separate element, with an additional `\0` character as a string terminator.

I quoted "same", because there are some differences between `char * array` and `char array[]`.
If you want to read more, take a look at [C: differences between char pointer and array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array)

Comment: Those aren't "minor" differences. And it's better to clarify them than leave the OP and future readers confused.

Comment: How is a read only array a _"minor"_ difference, and not relevant to the OP? If you say something like that, there's bound to be a follow up question within the next 15 minutes

Comment: I just linked to the proper topic, not to duplicate text.

Comment: Yeah, maybe the word "minor" was not in place here.