# When to use char a[] over char p* and vice versa?

Tags: c

Lately I've been learning all about the C language, and am confused as to ***when*** to use

```
char a[];
```

over

```
char *p;
```

when it comes to string manipulation. For instance, I can assign a string to them both like so:

```
char a[] = "Hello World!";
char *p = "Hello World!";
```

and view/access them both like:

```
printf("%s\n", a);
printf("%s\n", p);
```

and manipulate them both like:

```
printf("%c\n", &a[6]);
printf("%c\n", &p[6]);
```

So, what am I missing?

Comment: first of all, enable compiler warnings

Comment: Use whichever you want... is just syntactic sugar en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar

Comment: You miss the most important point which is the memory release, how long you want your object a to live in your program.

Comment: @zambotn: you're wrong. they are different.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath not for the code above. BTW you are right, in general case is not the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [char \*array and char array\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347170/char-array-and-char-array) also: your last `printf` calls are wrong, and you can't manipulate the value `p` points to, because it's an implicit `const char *`, pointing to read-only memory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
char a[] = "Hello World!";
```

This allocates modifiable array just big enough to hold the string literal (including terminating NUL char). Then it initializes the array with contents of string literal. If it is a local variable, then this effectively means it does `memcpy` at runtime, every time the local variable is created.

Use this when you need to modify the string, but don't need to make it bigger.

Also, if you have `char *ap = a;`, when `a` goes out of scope `ap` becomes a dangling pointer. Or, same thing, you can't do `return a;` when `a` is local to that function, because return value will be dangling pointer to now destroyed local variables of that function.

Note that using exactly this is rare. Usually you don't want an array with contents from string literal. It's much more common to have something like:

```
char buf[100]; // contents are undefined
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s/%s.%d", pathString, nameString, counter);
```

---

```
char *p = "Hello World!";
```

This defines pointer, and initializes it to point to string literal. Note that string literals are (normally) non-writable, so you really *should* have this instead:

```
const char *p = "Hello World!";
```

Use this when you need pointer to non-modifiable string.

In contrast to `a` above, if you have `const char *p2 = p;` or do `return p;`, these are fine, because pointer points to the string literal in program's constant data, and is valid for the whole execution of the program.

---

The string literals themselves, text withing double quotes, the actual bytes making up the strings, are created at compile time and normally placed with other constant data within the application. And then string literal in code concretely means address of this constant data blob.

Comment: One clarification might be helpful (or may just cause confusion).  In either case, the compiler will create a string literal and add it to the executable.  In the case of the array, the array is initialized at runtime (eg, the 'memcpy' you refer to happens at runtime, while the creation of the string literal happens at compile time.)  The pointer is also initialized at runtime, but the initialization doesn't copy the string--just its address.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Edited a bit based on your suggestion

Comment: So, if I was to compare this to PHP (being more familiar with), would I be right to assume that ```char *p;``` is similar to a PHP constant, and ```char a[];``` would be a normal PHP variable?

Comment: @NathanBishop I think that is dangerous thinking. C does not have "real" strings same way PHP (and almost everything else) has. Better think of C strings as C strings: Pointers to memory somewhere, which may be constant, may be in static data, stack or heap, and should have terminating NUL in it.

Comment: @NathanBishop I added a bit of text, which may help with understanding `a`.

Answer (score 2):

`char *` strings are read-only. They cannot be modified while `char[]` strings can be.

`char *str = "hello";`
`str[0] = 't'; // This is an illegal operation`

Whereas

`char str[] = "hello"; str[0] = 't'; // Legal, string becomes tello`

Comment: "`char *` strings are read-only" Only if you set them equal to a string literal (as he did in the example). They are perfectly writable otherwise.

Comment: A `char *` never is read-only, because it's not a `const char const *`, but it can be made to point to `const char`, which is of course read-only. As ever: specifying the storage class makes it all clear