# copy one string in to other using pointer produce Garbage values why?

Tags: c

if take array it will be fine  but as i used *str1 and str2 it does not work

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void copystr(char* ,char*);

int main() 
{ 
    char *str1="xxx";
    char *str2= "yyy";

    copystr(str1, str2); 
    printf("\n %s",str2); 
 }
 void copystr(char *dest,char *src) 
 { 
     while(*src!='\0') 
         *dest++=*src++; 
     *dest='\0'; 
     return; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char *str = "some string"
```

Here str is a pointer pointing to a constant memory, which can't be edited and leads to undefined behaviour.

But If you declare like

```
char str2[] = "some string"
```

Now str2 above is pointing to a memory which is not constant and can be changed. Thus will work.

More explanation here:
[char *array and char array[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347170/char-array-and-char-array)

Answer (score 0):

Destination string `str1` is a string literal. String literals are non modifiable. Any attempt to modify it will invoke [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).