# Where am I going wrong with my memory management?

Tags: c, memory-management, ecobee

https://gist.github.com/macarr/b49c0097666a613f639c4eab931f31d4

I'm making a little app in C that's supposed to connect to the ecobee API. Ignore for the moment that this is dumb/terrible/why god are you using C as a REST API client, it's a personal project for the fun of it.

I'm currently running into a problem with memory management. I've annotated the provided gist with comments and snipped out code that I don't believe is related. Basically, the app works *exactly* as expected until I reach getTokens. Then the following code freaks the heck out:

```
struct authorizations getTokens(char* apiKey, char* authCode) {
  char* body = "grant_type=ecobeePin&code=";
  body = concat(body, authCode);
  printf("%s!!!!!!!!!!\n", body); //as expected
  concat2(body, "&client_id=");
  printf("%s!!!!!!!!!!\n", body); //as expected
  concat2(body, apiKey);
  printf("%s!!!!!!!!!!\n", body); //garbage
  ...
```

See the gist for the function of concat and concat2.

```
char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char* result;
    result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);//+1 for the zero-terminator
    if(!result) {
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    printf("CONCAT1: %s\n", result);
    return result;
}

void concat2(char *s1, const char *s2) {
    char temp[strlen(s1)];
    strcpy(temp, s1);
    printf("%s:%s\n", temp, s2);
    s1 = realloc(s1, strlen(temp) + strlen(s2) + 1);//+1 for the null terminator
    if(!s1) {
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(s1, temp);
    strcat(s1, s2);
    printf("CONCAT2: %s\n", s1);
}
```

At the end of my function, I `free(body)`, which kills the application because apparently body has already been freed. I guess one of my `realloc`s aren't working or something?

What confuses me most is that when I was working with bad data two days ago (making invalid calls to the api and just pulling info from the errors to populate the requests going forward - I didn't have a login set up then), everything was working fine. Once I started getting real data, the application started "stack smashing". This is as far as I was able to push it last night.

Additionally, any general advice on where I'm going wrong in regards to string concatenation and pointer manipulation would be welcome. Assume I've already heard why I shouldn't be using C as a REST API client

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347170/char-array-and-char-array - disregard, I didn't look at `concat` and `concat2`

Comment: "See the gist for the function of concat and concat2." - See [ask] for how this site works and what you are expected to provide. In short: What if that site goes offline?

Comment: There is a problem with `concat2`. Change it to return a value like `body = concat2(body, "&client_id=");`

Comment: You need to give a long hard thought to the fact that **`realloc` returns a value**. Why is this value needed? Couldn't we just say `realloc(ptr, newsize)` and be done with it? Now when you have answered this question, look at `concat2`.

Comment: Please post the body of `concat` and `concat2` in your question - I can't reach the link provided.

Comment: Also `char temp[strlen(s1)];` off-by-one error --> `char temp[strlen(s1)+1];` note: `realloc` saves the original contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @n.m. and @BLUEPIXY, there is a serious problem with `concat2`.  Assuming you don't want to spend any more time figuring it out for yourself, **spoilers follow...**

The primary issue is that `concat2` dutifully takes the buffer pointed to by `s1`, reallocs it to ensure it's big enough for the concatenation, storing the pointer to the brand new resized buffer in `s1`.  It then does the string concatenation into that new buffer, and then -- when the function ends -- it throws the all-important new pointer value in `s1` away.  After the first call to `concat2`, your `getTokens` function is under the mistaken impression that the buffer is still located at `body`, but the location might very well have been changed!

(Depending on how the allocator works on your particular platform, it may or many not *actually* change, depending on the old and new sizes and allocator details, but you need to assume it might have changed.)  So, if you rewrite `concat2` as:

```
char* concat2(char *s1, const char *s2) {
    char temp[strlen(s1)];
    strcpy(temp, s1);
    s1 = realloc(s1, strlen(temp) + strlen(s2) + 1);//+1 for the null terminator
    if(!s1) {
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(s1, temp);
    strcat(s1, s2);
    return(s1);  /* IMPORTANT: new buffer location! */ 
}
```

and modify your `concat2` calls so they look like:

```
body = concat2(body, "&client_id=");
...
body = concat2(body, apiKey);
```

you will find that things work better.

Another point to note: `realloc` *already* copies the previous contents of the buffer to the new buffer (up to its originally `malloc`ed size; any added memory will be uninitialized), so you don't need to use the `temp` buffer and extra copying at all and `concat2` can be simplified to:

```
char* concat2(char *s1, const char *s2) {
    s1 = realloc(s1, strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);//+1 for the null terminator
    if(!s1) {
        exit(1);
    }
    /* now s1 points to the original string at the beginning
     * of a sufficiently large buffer
     */
    strcat(s1, s2);
    return(s1);
}
```

Comment: `char temp[strlen(s1)];
    strcpy(temp, s1);` is UB as `temp[]` is too small.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! I think I've got a better handle on pointers in general now, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, you have a *major* problem here:

```
s1 = realloc(s1, strlen(temp) + strlen(s2) + 1);
```

This can potentially change the value of `s1`, which is *promptly lost as soon as you exit the function*.  You do not return this new pointer value back to the caller, so it's using the old, now *invalid* pointer value.  Hence the lossage.

You need to make the changed value of `s1` available to the caller, meaning you must pass a pointer to it:

```
void concat2(char **s1, const char *s2) {
    /**
     * You do not need to preserve the contents of s1 here - if successful,
     * realloc will copy the contents of s1 to the new memory; if not, 
     * it will leave the existing contents in place.  
     * 
     * Because realloc can return NULL on failure, you should *not*
     * assign the result back to the original pointer, but instead
     * assign it to a temporary; that way, if realloc does fail, you
     * don't lose the reference to the previously allocated memory
     */
    char *tmp = realloc(*s1, strlen(*s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);//+1 for the null terminator
    if(!tmp) {
        // handle realloc error
    }
    *s1 = tmp;
    strcat(*s1, s2);
    printf("CONCAT2: %s\n", *s1);
}
```

You'd then call this as

```
concat2(&body, "&client_id=");
...
concat2(&body, apiKey);
```