# what is different between passing in char *argv[] and declaring char *argv?

Tags: c, ruby

My c skills are very rusty, so I apologize if this is a dumb question,  but I could not even think were to look for the answer to this simple question.
This code compiles without any warnings:

```
#include <ruby.h>

int run_script( int argc, char *argv[] )  {
  ruby_sysinit(&argc,  &argv);
}
```

But when I compile this code, I get the following warning:

```
#include <ruby.h>

int run_script( char * parameters )  {
    int argc=0;
    char *argv[1];
    ruby_sysinit(&argc,  &argv);
}

run_script_3.c: In function 'run_script':
run_script_3.c:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ruby_sysinit' from incompatible pointer type
```

it seems like i am passing the same pointer type in both cases.

Comment: Just to confirm: Same compile options (warning levels, etc.) in both cases?

Comment: yes same exact command line options, just the different file contents

Comment: What's th prototype of ruby_sysinit ?

Comment: void ruby_sysinit(int *argc, char ***argv);
which I think makes sense, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of `ruby_sysinit` is as follows (correct me if I picked the wrong ruby version, I don't have the header file on my system):

```
void ruby_sysinit(int *argc, char ***argv);
```

This means that the following compiles:

```
extern void ruby_sysinit(int *argc, char ***argv);

int run_script(char * params)  {
    int argc = 0;
    char **argv;
    ruby_sysinit(&argc, &argv);
}
```

Now, when you declare `char *argv[1]`, you tell the compiler that this is an array with one element. This is not the same as `char **argv`.

EDIT: you might find [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array) and [this article (as linked in the other question)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/44463) useful.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that an array in formal parameter declaration is equivalent to pointer. Declaration of

```
int run_script( int argc, char *argv[] )  { ... }
```

is equivalent to

```
int run_script( int argc, char **argv)  { ... }
```

because you can not send an array as parameter. You can send only a pointer and even if you put an array as actual parameter it is always converted to a pointer. Then if you put `&argv` you are getting address of this parameter, so it is an address in system stack where `argv`'s value is stored.

On the other hand array in code is still an array, which is different type. In your case `&argv` is of type `char ***` inside the first version of `run_script` while it is of type `char *(*)[1]` in the second version. It looks like the same type, but it is not. In run time, there is even bigger difference, because your two invocations are sending two completely different values to `ruby_sysinit`.

Your second example:

```
int run_script( char * parameters )  {
    int argc=0;
    char *argv[1];
    ruby_sysinit(&argc,  &argv);
}
```

will probably cause segfault because opearator `&` applied on an array gives the pointer to the first element of the array. So the call `ruby_sysinit(&argc,  &argv);` is sending the same values as `ruby_sysinit(&argc,  argv);`, i.e. a value which points to `char*`, not to pointer to `char*` as expected by `ruby_sysinit`.