# Array Pointers vs Regular Pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am a total beginner to C so please, work with my ignorance. Why does a normal pointer

`int* ptr = &a;` has two spaces in memory (one for the pointer variable and one for the value it points to) and an array pointer `int a[] = {5};` only has one memory space (if I print out

`printf("\n%p\n", a)` I get the same address as if I printed out: `printf("\n%p\n", &a)`.

The question is, shouldn't there be a memory space for the pointer variable `a` and one for its value which points to the first array element? It does it with the regular pointer `int* ptr = &a;`

Comment: Your first example has only one "space" -- that for the pointer itself.  `a` is defined elsewhere.  But important to remember is that a C pointer contains no indication as to the size of the array it addresses, if it even addresses an array.

Comment: (You can't really begin to understand C pointers until you set aside any expectation that they're "logical".)

Comment: You have to keep in mind if `a` is declared as an array, then `a` is notationally same as `&a`.

Comment: @HotLicks Licks I am sure that if they were engineer by one person, another person can understand them as well. You really did not provide me with a helpful answer but thank you.

Comment: @polymorph That's just the rule. If `arr` is an array, typing `arr` gives you a pointer to the first element. If you take the address of `arr` you also get a pointer to the first element.

Comment: The main thing to understand is that there's really no such thing as a "array pointer" in C.  There's barely a concept of an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little unclear from your question (and assuming *no* compiler optimization), but if you first declare a variable and then a pointer to that variable,

```
int a = 4;
int *p = &a;
```

then you have two different variables, it makes sense that there are two memory slots.  You might change p to point to something else, and still want to refer to a later

```
int a = 4;
int b = 5;

int *p = &a; // p points to a

// ...

p = &b; // now p points to b
a = 6; // but you can still use a
```

The array declaration just allocates memory on the stack.  If you wanted to do the same with a pointer, on the heap, you would use something like malloc or calloc (or new in c++)

```
int *p = (int*)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
*p = 4;
```

but of course remember to free it later (delete in c++)

```
free(p);
p = 0;
```

Comment: What I still don't understand is where the `a` variable lives. If the pointer has an address for itself and one for its value, why doesn't `a`?

Comment: Every variable has an address (again assuming no compiler optimizations).  Both ````a```` and ````p```` are regular variables.  The value of a is 4.  The value of p is the address of a.  Make sense?

Comment: Right, we established that `a` has an address but shouldn't its value which it points to, also have an address? `p` like `a` has an address but one for its value as well, which is `a` but `a` has the same address for its value and itself?

Comment: I think you're over-thinking it.  On a 32-bit system, the type of int and * are essentially the same thing - they're 4-byte values.  Both ````a```` and ````p```` refer to one 4-byte slot in memory.  In the ````a```` slot is the value 4; and in the ````p```` slot is the value 0xfffa or something, which is the address of a.

Comment: A pointer is a type in C, which means it has special semantics, but that is a function of the language and not the actual memory.  You can use an int as a pointer if you want, e.g. ````int a = 3; *(&a) = 4;```` although it will almost certainly segfault, or worse.

Comment: I get it, I do tend to overthink these things and lose myself in the process. Thank you.

Comment: @polymorph a ends up being a constant pointing to the first memory location of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The main misunderstanding here is that `&a` return not pointer to pointer as it expected that's because in C language there some difference between [] and * (Explanation here: [Difference between [] and *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array))
If you try to `&a` if a was an pointer (e.g. int *a) then you obtain a new memory place but when your use a static array (i.e. int a[]) then it return address of the first array element. I'll also try to clarify this by mean of the next code block.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // for cycles
    int k; 

    printf("That is a pointer case:\n");
    // Allocate memory for 4 bytes (one int is four bytes on x86 platform, 
    // can be differ for microcontroller e.g.)
    int c = 0xDEADBEEF;
    unsigned char *b = (unsigned char*) &c;
    printf("Value c: %p\n", c);
    printf("Pointer to c: %p\n", &c);
    printf("Pointer b (eq. to c): %p\n", b);
    // Reverse order (little-endian in case of x86)
    for (k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        printf("b[%d] = 0x%02X\n", k, b[k]);

    // MAIN DIFFERENCE HERE: (see below)    
    unsigned char **p_b = &b;
    // And now if we use & one more we obtain pointer to the pointer
    // 0xDEADBEEF <-- b <-- &p_b
    // This pointer different then b itself
    printf("Pointer to the pointer b: %p\n", p_b);

    printf("\nOther case, now we use array that defined by []:\n");
    int a[] = {5,1};
    int *ptr = &a;
    // 'a' is array but physically it also pointer to location
    // logically it's treat differ other then real pointer
    printf("'a' is array: %x\n", a);
    // MAIN DIFFERENCE HERE: we obtain not a pointer to pointer
    printf("Pointer to 'a' result also 'a'%x\n", &a);
    printf("Same as 'a': %x\n", ptr);
    printf("Access to memory that 'a' pointes to: \n%x\n", *a);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. In first case,

`int* ptr = &a;`

you have one variable `a` already declared and hence present in memory. Now you declare another variable `ptr` (to hold the address, in C variables which hold address of another variable are called **pointers**), which again requires memory in the same way as `a` required.

In second case,

`int a[] = {5};`

You just declare one variable (which will hold a collection of `ints`), hence memory is allocated accordingly for `a[]`.

Answer (score 0):

In this expression, `int* p = &a;` `p` has only one memory location, of the WORD size of your CPU, most probably, and it is **to store the address (memory location) of another variable**.

When you do `*p` you are *dereferencing* `p`, which means you are getting the value of what *p points to*.  In this particular case that would be the value of `a`.  `a` has *its own location in memory*, and `p` only **points to it**, but does not itself store `a`s content.

When you have an array, like `int a[] = {5};`, you have a series (or one) of memory locations, and they are filled with values.  These are actual locations.

Arrays in C can *decay* to a pointer, so when you `printf` like you did with your array, you get the same address, whether you do `a` or `&a`.  This is because of *array to pointer decay*.

`a` is still the same location, and is only that location. `&a` actually returns a pointer to `a`, but that pointer sits else where in memory.  If you did `int* b = &a;` then `b` here would not have the same location as `a`, however, it would *point to* `a`.

Comment: Dereferencing is with `*` and `&` takes the address.

Comment: a is the address of the first element of the array. In that sense, C is somewhat forgiving by allowing &a which would mean address of address of first element of array. Not necessarily consistent but accepted by the compiler.

Comment: @Jamie yes you're right. I'm derping. I fixed it now.

Comment: @TonyTheLion Removed the down vote; also "`p`" doesn't exist in the example you give, `ptr` does.

Comment: "*a actually returns a pointer to a". Nope, it returns the value of the first element of a.

Answer (score 0):

ptr is a variable containing a memory address. You can assign various memory addresses to ptr. a is a constant representing a fixed memory address of the first element of the array. As such you can do:

```
ptr = a;
```

but not

```
a = ptr;
```

Answer (score -1):

Pointers point to an area in memory. Pointers to `int` point to an area large enough to hold a value of `int` type.

If you have an array of `int` and make a pointer point to the array first element

```
int array[42];
int *p = array;
```

the pointer still points to a space wide enough for an int.

On the other hand, if you make a different pointer point to the whole array, this new pointer points to a larger area that starts at the same address

```
 int (*q)[42]; // q is a pointer to an array of 42 ints
 q = &array;
```

the address of both `p` and `q` is the same, but they point to differently sized areas.

Comment: Emphasis: the pointer storage in both cases is the same, what they point _too_ is different.

Comment: Nope. Even in the first case, p[10] is perfectly legal and equivalent to array[10].