# Giving a char array a default value with a constructor in a class c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor, char

I'm writing a little program that takes input from the user. The input being an integer, for the number of the student, 2 double numbers as grades, and the field of study, which has to be a character array of maximum size 20.
Now when writing the class, I'm not quite sure how to give the character array a default value in the constructor.

This is what I've written with the class and constructor.

```
class nemandi
{
public:
    nemandi(int num, double g1, double g2, char field[]);
    void birta();
    friend bool operator <(nemandi& nem1, nemandi& nem2);
private:
    int studentNumber;
    double grade1;
    double grade2;
    double medaltal();
    char fieldOfStudy[20];
};


nemandi::nemandi(int num, double g1, double g2, char field[])
{
    studentNumber = num;
    grade1 = g1;
    grade2 = g2;
    fieldOfStudy[20] = field[20];
}
```

This doesn't work, and I haven't been able to find a solution to this online. Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to give the char array a default value in the constructor??

Thanks in advance !

EDIT: Replacing `fieldOfStudy[20] = field[20];` with `memcpy(fieldOfStudy, field, sizeof(fieldOfStudy));` did the trick ! Thanks for helping out guys :)

Comment: Do you have to use `char[]`? Or can you use `std::string`?

Comment: Just a tip: try using better variable names. I know you know what they are used for, but people reading it have no idea.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind thanks. And yes, it says I have to use a char[], I had no problem doing this using string.

Comment: Use a loop and copy across each array indice

Comment: Apparently, this is a C-style string, so you can use `strcpy` to copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fieldOfStudy[20] = field[20];
```

You are just assigning the char at position 20 from field to fieldOfStudy. Use memcpy instead:

```
memcpy(fieldOfStudy, field, sizeof(fieldOfStudy));
```

Comment: `strcpy` would be more efficient if they are C strings.

Comment: I think memcpy is faster as the size is known and fixed, strcpy simple copies till the null-terimnation.

Answer (score 0):

This line `fieldOfStudy[20] = field[20];` sets the `char` at position 20 in `fieldOfStudy` to the value of the `char` at position 20 in `field`.

Keep in mind that `fieldOfStudy` is a pointer to a char, and `char fieldOfStudy[20]` just tells the compiler that there will be 19 more `char`s after the one that `fieldOfStudy` is pointing to.

Comment: Thanks @MikeSeymour, I didn't know. If any else has the same misconception: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array

Answer (score 0):

A character array does not work the way you want with assignment and comparison operators, which is why the std::string class was created.

```
nemandi::nemandi(int num, double eink1, double eink2, const std::string& lina)
{
    studentNumber = num;
    einkun1 = eink1;
    einkun2 = eink2;
    namslina = lina;
}
```

or

```
nemandi::nemandi(int num, double eink1, double eink2, const std::string& lina)
    : studentNumber(num)
    , einkun1 (eink1)
    , einkun2 (eink2)
    , namslina (lina)
{
}
```

If your case requires arrays then you have to use something like memcpy to copy the data

```
nemandi::nemandi(int num, double eink1, double eink2, char lina[])
    : studentNumber(num)
    , einkun1 (eink1)
    , einkun2 (eink2)
{
    memcpy(namslina, lina, sizeof(namslina));
}
```

Which works if you always want 20 characters copied and you can assure that the parameter is at least that long.  If you're working with C style null terminated strings you would use "strcpy".

Comment: Thank you, do I need to include some packet in order for memcpy or strcpy to work?

Comment: @Birgir: They're both in `<cstring>`. Make sure you check the size of `lina` before copying; the code in this answer will go out of bounds if it's smaller than 20 characters.

Comment: Ahh got it, and it worked just fine ! I had already written this program using string which I had no trouble with, but I was doing some exercises I had access to on the internet, and that particular problem required me to use char array. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

If you need to initialize **c-string** by default value in class constructor, you may do the following:

```
class A {
  char str[20];
public:
  A() {

    // `def_str` will be created only once upon
    // construction of first `A` instance 
    static char const def_str[] = "default string";

    strcpy(str, def_str);

  }
```