# extern declaration, T* v/s T[]

Tags: c, language-lawyer, extern, declaration

I saw following piece of code in a legacy project.

```
/* token.c */
struct token id_tokens[MAX_TOKENS];

/* analyse.c (v1) */
extern struct token *id_tokens; /* Raised my eyebrow, id_token declares a pointer */
```

I insisted on changing `analyse.c` to contain the declaration as below:

```
/* analyse.c (v2) */
extern struct token id_tokens[]; /* I am happy with this. id_tokens declares array of unspecified size. */
```

I want `v2` because `pointer to T` is not same as `array of T`. My friend's counter argumented that behaviour of both are same, so it doesn't matter whether I use v1 and v2.

**Question 1:** Does array of incomplete type deplete to a pointer?

**Question 2:** Is my friend right that both versions are behaviorally guaranteed to be equivalent?

Comment: See [this](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr1.html) **Array are not pointers** Many duplicates, idk what's confusion, in a way, you and your friend both are wrong

Comment: Arrays and pointers can be used interchangeably, because an array is just a group of variables of the same type in a line in memory, and a pointer simply points to the first element of a group of variables of the same type in a line in memory.  That is why `char *foo` is the same as `char foo[]`

Comment: @Gophyr You are talking my friend's language. Check the answers below. They are indeed different.

Comment: @GyaptiJain Technically an array is just a pointer to the beginning of the memory space as well.  The memory is the same in both cases, it is only the representation in the code that looks different.

Comment: However, the array has a definite size associated with it, but that can be overrun, i.e. buffer overflows, etc.

Comment: @Gophyr No no no... array and pointers are not same. Only some of their usage may appear same, nothing more than that.

Comment: @GyaptiJain How can they be completely interchangeable then?  The compiler represents the array as a pointer to the beginning of a section of memory.  The only difference is that when you declare an array, you give the compiler an expected size of the array.

Comment: @GyaptiJain If analyse.c v1 works, then this proves my point.

Comment: @Gophyr No `analyse.c v1` should not work. It appears in the legacy code mentioned by OP, this id_tokens is not used or worked well for some legacy (may be non-compliant) compiler.

Comment: @GyaptiJain I am not asking if it should work, I am asking if it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* token.c */
struct token id_tokens[MAX_TOKENS];

/*
 id_tokens
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+...+-----+
  |     |     |     |     |   |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+...+-----+
    [0]   [1]   [2]   [3]  ...  [MAX_TOKEN-1]

  To access id_tokens[i], add offset of ith element
  i.e. i * sizeof(struct token) to the **address**
  of array token
 */
```

So in your `analyse.c`, following instructions would be generated with this declaration.

> 1. `extern struct token id_tokens[];`
>       id_tokens[i]
>       a. Address of id_tokens that might be linked from other compilation unit
>      is taken
>       b. offset of i is added
>       c. Value is referenced

```
/* analyse.c (v1) */
extern struct token *id_tokens;

/*
 id_tokens
  +------+           +-----+...
  | addr |---------->|     |
  +------+           +-----+...


  To access id_tokens[i], fetch **contetnts** of pointer
  token, add offset of ith element i.e. i * sizeof(struct token)
  is added to this.
 */
```

So in your `analyse.c`, following instructions would be generated with this declaration:

> 2. `extern struct token *id_tokens;`
>       id_tokens[i]
>       a. Contents from address of id_tokens that is linked from other
>      compilation unit is taken.
>       (Will result in compilation error if present in same compilation unit because of type mismatch)
>       b. offset of i is added
>       c.
>      Value is referenced

Let's assume sizeof `id_token[0]` is `2` byte and sizeof pointer to `id_token[0]` is `4` byte.

Your later declaration may (mis)interprete the `id_tokens[0]` & `id_tokens[1]` as an address and add some offset to it (which may be an existing or non-existing address, aligned or non-aligned address who knows).

If it is your good day, program may crash or segfault immediately and you get a chance to fix the bug. If it is your bad day, program may just mess up with some other memory or communicate a wrong state to some module which can result in difficult to track bug and cause a nightmare.

---

<sup>Now I guess you understand why you got `(nil)` as output in [Mr. 32's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924257/extern-declaration-t-v-s-t/26924856#26924856).</sup>

Answer (score 8):

The first version is wrong. Arrays are NOT pointers, the declaration `extern struct token *id_tokens;` doesn't match the definition type `struct token id_tokens[MAX_TOKENS];`.

Reference: [C FAQ:  I had the definition char a[6] in one source file, and in another I declared extern char *a. Why didn't it work?](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr1.html).  Also, see [this](http://c-faq.com/decl/extarraysize.html).

Answer (score 2):

lets understand same stuff by program

test.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"head.h"
struct token id_tokens[10];
int main()
{
printf("In original file: %p",id_tokens);
testing();
}
```

head.h

```
struct token {
int temp;
};
```

---

test1.c with v1

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"head.h"
extern struct token* id_tokens;
void testing () {
printf("In other file %p",id_tokens);
}
```

**Output :** In original file: 0x601040In other file (nil)

---

test1.c with v2

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"head.h"
extern struct token id_tokens[];
void testing () {
printf("In other file %p",id_tokens);
}
```

**Output :** In original file: 0x601040In other file 0x601040

---

**This clearly shows that v1 is not correct and v2 is correct.**

Comment: Not casting id_tokens to `void *` for `%p` is UB. Why is it nil?

Comment: In v1, You have declared id_tokens as extern pointer to struct token but there is not any global struct token in both files so it is null.

Comment: +1 Very pragmatic way. Is there a spec reference suggesting the same>

Comment: this things should be in spec. I do not read spec much. I usually clear my doubt by making such small program and clear the concept.

Comment: @Mr.32 You can check my answer to understand why does it happen. Keypoint, when you write `struct token id_tokens[10];` in global scope, memory is initialized with zeros.