# Difference between array of pointers (*A)[] and double pointer **A

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, matrix, heap-memory

With one dimensional arrays (or integers for example) I know how to create pointers both for allocation in the heap and in the stack

-Pointer in the stack and array in the stack

```
int a[3];
int *ptr=a;
```

-Pointer in the stack and array in the heap

```
int *ptr=new int[3];
```

---

But for matrix (for example 3x2) the pointer can be created as an array of pointers `int (*A)[3]` or as a double pointer `int **A`.

I would like to know the main difference between these two way to create a pointer to a multidimensional array.

In particular I've seen the array of pointers used to create pointer to a matrix array stored in the stack as:

```
int A[2][3];
int (*ptr)[3]=A;
```

And I've seen the double pointer used for matrices allocated in the heap

```
int **ptr= new *[3];
for(int i=0; i<=3; i++) int ptr[i]=new [2];
```

But is it also possible to use the array of pointer for the heap and the double pointer for the stack?

And again, more generally, what are the main difference between the array of pointers and the double pointer?

Comment: This sort of question pops up once a week on SO. What did you find when you searched for it?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) details array internals in C. There are obvious differences (some of the technique cannot be applied to C++), but the general gist of memory layout is the same.

Comment: For matrices I usually prefer to have an one-dimensional array (btw. that is what `int a[2][3]` normally does under the hood AFAIK), the performance is much better because of the contiguous memory (compared to separate allocation of each row or column with `int *a[2]`). Also, for the same reason (dcache performance) it does matter whether your matrix is row-major or column-major and how you iterate it then.

Comment: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746434/double-pointer-vs-array-of-pointersarray-vs-array / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491687/difference-between-double-pointer-and-array-of-pointers / many more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between double pointer and array of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491687/difference-between-double-pointer-and-array-of-pointers)

Comment: `int (*A)[3]` isn't an array of pointers. It is a pointer to an array of length 3.

Answer (score 1):

From the C++ (2017) Standard (7.2 Array-to-pointer conversion)

> 1 An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown
>   bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The
>   temporary materialization conversion (7.4) is applied. **The result is
>   a pointer to the first element of the array**.

Thus let's assume that you have an array like this

```
T A[N1][N2]...[Nn];
```

where `T` is some type and `[N1][N2]...[Nn]` is an informal record of dimensions of the array. Then this declaration can be written also like

```
T ( A[N1] )[N2]...[Nn];
```

To declare a pojnter to the first element of the array all you beed is to substitute `( A[N1] )` for `( *ptr )` in the declaration.

```
T ( A[N1] )[N2]...[Nn];
T ( *ptr  )[N2]...[Nn] = A;
```

For example taking the declaration from the question

```
int A[2][3];
```

you can rewrite it like

```
int ( A[2] )[3];
```

Now it is easy to declare a pointer to the first element of the array

```
int ( *ptr )[3] = A;
```

Dereferencing the pointer you get the first "row" of the type `int[3]` of the two-dimensional array

On the other hand, if you have a declaration of an array of pointers like

```
int * A[3];
```

which can be rewritten like

```
int * ( A[3] );
```

then to get a declaration of a pointer you can write

```
int * ( *ptr ) = A;
```

that is the same as

```
int **ptr = A;
```

So dereferencing the pointer you will get an object of the type `int *` that is in turn a pointer.

So for this declaration

```
int ( *ptr )[3] = A;
```

the pointed object is a one-dimensional array. For example you can write

```
std::cout << sizeof( *ptr ) << std::endl;
```

and you will get a value that is equal to `sizeof( int[3] )` that is equal to `3 * sizeof( int )`

As for this declaration

```
int * A[3];
int **ptr = A;
```

the pointed object is a pointer of the type `int *`. If to write for this pointer

```
std::cout << sizeof( *ptr ) << std::endl;
```

then you will get a value that is equal to `sizeof( int * )`

Let's consider this code snippet

```
int **ptr = new int *[2];
for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) ptr[i] = new int[3];
```

In the first statement there is dynamically allocated a one-dimensional array of the type `int *[2]`.

Then in the loop there are dynamically created 2 arrays of the type `int[3]` and pointers to first elements of the arrays are assigned to elements of the previously allocated one-dimensional array.

So in whole there are dynamically allocated 3 arrays: one of the type `int *[2]` and two of the type `int [3]`. That is there are allocated three separate extents of memory.

Instead you could write

```
int ( *ptr )[3] = new int[2][3];
```

In this case there is allocated dynamically only one two-dimensional array and the declared pointer `ptr` points to the first "row" of the array. That is there is allocated only one extent of memory.