# short array in typedef struct in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, typedef, short

```
typedef struct
{
short data[];

short sampleData[];

BOOL sample[];

}customMembers;
```

I declared like this but I am getting error like following

**"Filed has incomplete type short[]"**

Please help me

Comment: @Antzi I understand the difference. But I want to use Java short[] array in Objective-c. What is the equivalent in Objective-c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide a length like this `short data[42]` for your arrays or define it as a pointer `short *`.

If not, the size of the struct would be unknown.

See [C: differences between char pointer and array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array) for more informations about the difference between the two.

Comment: @iOS_DeviOS Yes, Objective C is a super set of C. Any C code can be compiled and used from objective C.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am unable to accept your answer.

Comment: @iOS_DeviOS I think you need some time before accepting... Or maybe the down vote prevent new users to do it.

Comment: Thanks alot. So, short * and short[] both are equal. is that correct?

Comment: @iOS_DeviOS No: They retain the same difference as in C, see the link in the updated answer.