# Modifying a char array inside a function in C

Tags: c, arrays

So I've been playing around with C lately and have been trying to understand the intricacies of passing by value/reference and the ability to manipulate a passed-in variable inside a function. I've hit a road block, however, with the following:

```
void modifyCharArray(char *input)
{
    //change input[0] to 'D'
    input[0] = 'D';
}

int main()
{
    char *test = "Bad";
    modifyCharArray(test);
    printf("Bad --> %s\n", test);
}
```

So the idea was to just modify a char array inside a function, and then print out said array after the modification completed. However, this fails, since all I'm doing is modifying the value of `input` that is passed in and not the actual memory address.

In short, is there any way I can take in a `char *input` into a function and modify its original memory address without using something like `memcpy` from string.h?

Comment: "However, this fails, since all I'm doing is modifying the value of input that is passed in and not the actual memory address." No you *are* passing in a memory address, and modifying the value it points to. The only thing you are doing wrong is providing an address you are not allowed to modify.

Comment: *All* parameters in C are passed by value. In this case, the value being passed happens to be a pointer value, the address of the first element of the string literal `"Bad"`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> In short, is there any way I can take in a `char *input` into a function and modify its original memory address without using something like `memcpy` from string.h?

Yes, you can. Your function `modifyCharArray` is doing the right thing. What you are seeing is caused by that fact that

```
char *test = "Bad";
```

creates `"Bad"` in read only memory of the program and `test` points to that memory. Changing it is cause for undefined behavior.

If you want to create a modifiable string, use:

```
char test[] = "Bad";
```

Comment: The second answer has a good visual for this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't aware there was a difference between `char *test` and `char test[]` but it's good to know now. Appreciate the help

Comment: There are a lot of differences between `char *test = "Bad";` and `char test[] = "Bad";`, and you need to be aware of at least some of them (the primary one at the moment being that the array can be modified but the string literal can't — another is that if you have your compiler set appropriately fussy, it will tell you when you assign a pointer to string literal to a non-const `char *`).