# input directory as command line arguement in c

Tags: c, linux, command-line-interface

i am building a program that copies directories to each other, but i can only get it to work hard coded.

i want the directory to be input by the user via a command line argument.

i have used

```
char    SrcPath[]    = argv[1];
```

however when i hard code it like

```
char SrcPath[] = "home/user/Desktop/cat"; it works fine.
```

but this doesn't work, can anybody explain why / suggest a way to do this?
and is there a special way that directories have to be input when used in a CLI?

Comment: What is the error you get when you try to get the directory from the command line?

Comment: i just get my "cannot open directory" message that occurs when there's an error with finding the directory

Comment: I think everyone was assuming but never mentioned: You understand that "home/user/Desktop/cat1" is a relative path and not an absolute path, right? Unless that directory is reachable from where the program start(at root "/"), then you can't change directory into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argv[]` is an array of char pointers, therefore when you use `argv[1]` you are obtaining the second item in the array which is a char pointer. As James suggested if you want to store the value of `argv[1]` which is a memory address you have to use a identical type which in this case is a `char *`.

If you need to save the directory path for any sort of processing or manipulation, you will need to do something like this to store the command line argument inside a char array.

```
char srcPath[100];
int i;
for (i = 0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++) {
    srcPath[i] = argv[1][i];
}
```

array names are pointers so using the subscript `[]` dereferences it. The same can be said for char arrays which is what is stored inside of `argv[]`

Comment: thanks so much for the response, but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: aOpenDir = opendir(SrcPath); 

    if(!aOpenDir)
    printf("\n ERROR! Directory can not be open");

and when i try to execute the program i am entering 

./a.out "home/user/Desktop/cat1" would this perhaps be the problem?

Comment: I would need to see more of the source file to see what's going on. Is opendir returning NULL? opendir is suppose to return a pointer stream to the opened directory and NULL if an error occurs

Comment: i figured out the issue, the code was right the input i was using was wrong. thank you so much for your answet

Answer (score 3):

Making the change to `char *SrcPath = argv[1];` should work. Pointers and arrays are different things!

Comment: You could point here for elaboration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array

Comment: thank you for your response but i am still getting the same problem
aOpenDir = opendir(SrcPath); if(!aOpenDir) printf("\n ERROR! Directory can not be open"); and when i try to execute the program i am entering ./a.out "home/user/Desktop/cat1" would this perhaps be the problem?