# Argument of type "const char **" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"

Tags: c++

I get this error with this code:

```
string folder;
getline(cin, folder);

string folder2 = folder + "/index.txt";
const char* oldhtml[] = { folder2.c_str() };
folder2 = folder + "/index.html";
const char* newhtml[] = { folder2.c_str()};
rename(oldhtml, newhtml);
```

The error occurs with: `rename(oldhtml, newhtml);`

I am fairly new to C++. So if this is a simple fix I apologise

Comment: Can you provide the declaration of `rename()`, please?

Comment: @WorldSEnder: Presumably http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename

Comment: @FredLarson Is right. That's what I was doing. Sorry for the _very_ late reply

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you don't understand this line:

```
const char* oldhtml[] = { folder2.c_str() };
```

That declares an array of length 1. The array element is a pointer which is initialized with the result of `folder2.c_str()` (probably, pointing to the internal storage of the string).

However you then change `folder2` on the next line. This invalidates the result of any previous calls to `c_str`, so `oldhtml[0]` is now a dangling pointer.

A better way to write this code is to use `string` all the way:

```
string oldhtml = folder + "/index.txt";
string newhtml = folder + "/index.html";
rename(oldhtml.c_str(), newhtml.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

`const char* oldhtml[]` creates an array of `char*` (similar to `const char**`), basically, an array of string (many char*), when you want a string (one and only one `char*`).

To create a regular pointer, use:

`const char* oldhtml` or `const char oldhtml[]`.

Comment: actually it creates a `const char * []`. Arrays and pointers are different.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, runtime arrays and pointers are completely interchangable (apart from `delete[]`)

Comment: @WorldSEnder no. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array) for some discussion, or read the C FAQ (or C++ FAQ).

Comment: @MattMcNabb, that question is for compile-time-static arrays, not runtime arrays

Answer (score -1):

Use `const char* oldhtml = folder2.c_str()` instead: there's no need to have an array of `const char*`

Be aware though that `oldhtml` will only be valid for as long as `folder2` is in scope and remains unaltered. Which is doesn't. You modify it later. **Boom!**

By the way, if `rename` changes either input parameter, **then the program behaviour will be undefined.**

Comment: Presumably it is the Standard C++ function `std::rename(char const *old_filename, char const *new_filename);`