# Reading array of string in C

Tags: c, input, segmentation-fault, scanf, stdin

I need to read an array of n strings from 2 letters in each (e.g. n = 3, need to read something near "ab bf cs"). I use this code and get segmentation fault:

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
char array[n][2];
char *tmp;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    scanf("%s", &tmp);
    strcpy(array[i], tmp);
}
```

Please help me to fix it!

Answer (score 4):

**Problem 1**

To store a string of length 2, you need a `char` array of size 3. Use:

```
char array[n][3];
```

**Problem 2**

You are using `&tmp` in the call to `scanf`. That is wrong on two accounts.

1. The type is not appropriate. Type of `&tmp` is `char**`. `scanf` needs a `char*` with the `%s` format specifier.
2. `&tmp` cannot hold a string.

You could use

```
scanf("%s", tmp);
```

That will be OK from type point of view but it won't ok from run time point of view since `tmp` does not point to anything valid.

You can do away with `tmp` altogether and use:

```
scanf("%s", array[i]);
```

---

That entire block of code can be:

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
char array[n][3];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    // Make sure you don't read more than 2 chars.
    scanf("%2s", array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple things you need to fix here.

1. Remember that one "string" (`char[]`) always ends with a null terminating character `\0`. So, whenever you create a `char[]`, you must leave enough space for that. For example:

   `char str[3] = "foo";` looks like `['f', 'o', 'o']`, but

   `char str[4] = "foo";` looks like `['f', 'o', 'o', '\0']`.

   Unexpected consequences can occur when using the former.

   This means that you should change `char array[n][2]` to `char array[n][3]`.
2. Remember that [pointers are different than arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array). If you want to use a pointer, you must allocate memory for it, otherwise you will most likely seg fault.

   In your program, it's simple enough that you can probably get away with not using a pointer, especially since you know the the length of each string that you will be storing (2).

   You could change `char *tmp` to `char tmp[3]`.
3. You can actually refactor your code so you don't need the `tmp` variable at all. If you want, you can just store the word you read into the array directly. For example:

   ```
   scanf("%s", array[n]);
   ```
4. If you are *really* insistent on using that `tmp` variable as a `char *`, then allocate memory for it, like so:

   ```
   char *tmp = (char*)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
   ```
5. As a sidenote, if you are adhering to the ISO C90 standards, you shouldn't intermix variable declarations in code, so in your loop where you have `for(int i = 0...)`, you should declare `int i;` at the top of the file, and then assign it in the loop `for(i = 0...)`.

Comment: `char *tmp = (char*)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));` could be simplified to `char *tmp = malloc(3);` or `char *tmp = malloc(sizeof *tmp * 3);`

Answer (score 2):

First, as user3121023 pointed out in the comments, `char *tmp;` creates a pointer without memory allocated to it. scanf() needs an array, and you need space for the terminating `'\0'` (which is probably the source of your segmentation fault). So you could try `scanf("%s", array[i]);`.

Second, it's a good idea to use `"%2s"` instead of `"%s"` so the user doesn't input 3 digits and overflow your buffer.

Here's one solution.

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
char array[n][3];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    scanf("%2s", array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Disagree with "you can't declare an array the size of anything other than a constant or integer literal." C99 and optionally C11 allow variable length arrays.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of that. I've updated my answer.