# Use of pointers on strings

Tags: c, c-strings, char-pointer

I am really confused about the use of pointers on strings.
It feels like they obey different rules.
Consider the following code

1. ```
   char *ptr = "apple";// perfectly valid here not when declaring afterwards like next

   ptr = "apple"; // shouldn't it be *ptr = "apple"
   ```
2. Also `printf()` behaves differently -

   ```
   printf("%s", ptr) // Why should I send  the address instead of the value
   ```
3. Also I came across the following code in a book

   ```
   char str[]="Quest";
   char *p="Quest";

   str++; // error, constant pointer can't change

   *str='Z'; // works, because pointer is not constant

   p++; // works, because pointer is not constant

   *p = 'M'; // error, because string is constant
   ```

I can't understand what is supposed to imply

Please help, I can't find any info anywhere else

Comment: There's no string type in c. So you can't send "the value" to printf, if that makes sense. You can only send the first address to the array of characters.

Comment: 3 is a duplicate, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array

Comment: Why not put *ptr ?

Comment: [Pick a book, any book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @GauravPant Because that would be a single char.

Comment: "Why should I send  the address instead of the value" --> consider if the string was 100s, or millions of bytes long.  Certainly easier to pass to the function the beginning address of the string rather than the value.

Comment: `*ptr` is of type char. You cannot assign a string literal to a character.

Comment: Read a beginners C book and learn about pointers and arrays. Instead asking this elementary questions read. Everything is in the books

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char *ptr;
ptr = "apple"; // shouldn't it be *ptr =      "apple"
```

No, because `*ptr` would be a `char`. So, you may write `*ptr = 'a'` but you can't write as you suggest.

```
printf("%s", ptr) // Why should I send  the address instead of the value
```

Because a string in C, is the address of a sequence of characters (`char`) terminated by zero (the null character aka `\x0`).

```
char str[] = "Quest";
char *p = "Quest";

str++; // error, constant pointer can't change
```

No, a pointer can perfectly change, but here, `str` is an array (which is slightly different from being a pointer). But, thus, it cannot deal with pointer arithmetic.

```
*str='Z'; // works, because pointer is not constant
```

No, it works because `*str` should be a `char`.

```
p++; // works, because pointer is not constant
```

No, it works because, this time, this is a pointer (not an array).

```
*p = 'M'; // error, because string is constant
```

Same as above, this is a `char` again, so it works because it is the right type and not because the string is 'constant'. And, as stated by Michael Walz in the comments, even though it might compile, it will produce an undefined behavior at runtime (most likely a crash with `segfault`) because the specification do not tell if the string pointed by `*p` is read-only or not (yet, it seems that most of the modern compilers implementation decide to make it in read-only). Which might produce a `segfault`.

For more information, refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s).

Comment: Best to use `NULL` (uppercase) for the _null pointer constant_ as used in the context of pointers.  Suggest to use "the _null character_ aka `'\0'`)" to match the C spec's style.

Comment: I knew I was writing something strange when I wrote it... I fully agree.

Comment: *p = 'M' should work according to you since it's a char

Comment: Yes, but I meant "Same as above..." to match the case where it was dealing with `*p`. Not, "Same as above..." just a line above... Hmmm, not clear indeed... I rewrite the last sentence, then.

Comment: Tell me if you better understand this way.

Comment: @perror still not quite clear. You should make clear that `p` is a pointer to a string literal, and that modifying a string literal yields in UB. But `*p = 'M'` is of course syntactically correct. You should distinguish between compilation errors and runtime errors. `str++; ` won't compile.  `*p = 'M'` compiles but will yield in UB at runtime (most likely crash on modern systems).

Comment: @MichaelWalz is right, the program is not executing

Comment: Hum, the answer of Michael Walz is quite good. In fact, I do not feel right to paraphrase what he said in my answer. His comment is a good complement to my answer, I do not want to stole the paternity of it. But, you two are right, I should have detailed this point. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

"*" when used with a pointer means get the contents of what the pointer points to, in the case of:

```
    char* ptr;
```

ptr is a pointer to a character, you can assign it to a string like so:

```
   const char* ptr = "test";
```

The layout in memory of this is "t" followed by "e", "s", "t" and then finally a nul terminator '\0'.

When you assign it like ptr as above its assigning the pointer to the first memory location which happens to be a "t".

*ptr returns the contents of what ptr points to and is always the size of the type it is declared as in this example a "char", single byte.

*(++ptr) would return "e", as the ptr is incremented to the next location before returning the contents of what it now points to.

Answer (score 3):

1- I think you are making some confusion with variable declaration and definition. This line:

```
char *ptr = "apple";
```

declares a pointer to char and assigns the address of the first character "a" to the variable ptr. This line is equivalent to the following 2:

```
char* ptr;
ptr = "apple";
```

Now, string literals in C are read only. They are implicitly constant, it's the same as doing

```
const char* ptr;
```

So in fact, you can not change the contents of the location this pointer points to. Now, even if you could, the way you did it is wrong. Because ptr points to the location of the first character of the string, when you do *ptr you are accessing the contents of the first char of that string. So it expects a char, not a string. So it would be something like: `*ptr = 'a'`;

2-
Well, that's the way printf works. If you want to print a string with the %s specifier, it expects a pointer to that string, the address of the string's first character, not the string's value itself.

3- Now I'm going to comment your code.

```
str++; // error, constant pointer can't change
```

You are correct. Other people keep saying that arrays and pointers are slightly different, but they are not. Arrays are just an abstraction for the programmer to say that you're storing a sequence of values. At the assembly level, there is no difference at all. You could say that arrays are immutable pointers with mutable contents. An array stores the address of the first element of the sequence of values. You can change the contents of the array, but you can't change the address(the first element it points to).

```
*str='Z'; // works, because pointer is not constant
```

Now you're making some confusion. The pointer is actually constant, that is, you can not change the address it stores. But you can change the content the address points to, which is what the line above is doing. It's changing the first value of the sequence of values from the array.

```
p++; // works, because pointer is not constant
```

Correct. The pointer is not constant, although the content it points to is. You can change the address the pointer stores, but not the value it points at. String literals are mutable pointers to immutable strings.

```
*p = 'M'; // error, because string is constant
```

Correct, the string is immutable.

Answer (score 2):

1. `"SOME STRING"` creates a char sequence in memory ending in `\0` and returns its first char address so you can assign it to a pointer: 
   `char *ptr = "Hello";`
2. `printf` function also works with addresses and the type specifier define how it should read data from memory.
3. `char str[]="Quest";
   char *p="Quest";`
   in the first  one you are creating an array with 6 rooms and storing `'Q', 'u', 'e', 's', 't', '\0'` in it, and then you can change some index value by `str[2] = 'x'` but the array name itself is a constant that has the address to the first location it points to so you can't change it with something like `str++;`
   But in the second one `"Quest\0"` is a constant string saved into some location in memory and its first memory location stored in `p` so you can't change that but the pointer itself is not a `const` and you can do `p++;`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm only going to answer subquestion 1.  But you've touched on a frequent but subtle confusion in C, a slight mismatch between the way you initialize a pointer, versus assign to that pointer.  Watch carefully.

If I have an `int` variable, I can either initialize it when I declare it:

```
int i = 42;
```

Or, I can declare it on one line (without initializing it), and give it a value later:

```
int i;
i = 42;
```

No mystery there.  But when pointers are involved, it looks a little different.  Again, I can declare and initialize on one line:

```
char *ptr = "apple";
```

Or I can split the declaration and the assignment:

```
char *ptr;
ptr = "apple";
```

But, that looks weird at first -- based on the first syntax, shouldn't the second way look like this?

```
*ptr = "apple";         // WRONG
```

No, it shouldn't, and here's why.

`ptr` is a pointer to some characters.  It is one way of referring to a string in C.

`*` is the pointer-indirection operator.  In an expression, `*ptr` refers to the character (just the one character) that `ptr` points to.  So if we wanted to fetch the first character of the string, we could use `*` to do that:

```
printf("first character: %c\n", *ptr);
```

Note that the format in this `printf` call uses `%c`, because it's just printing one character.

We can also assign pointers.  If we're using pointers to `char`, and if we're therefore thinking of those pointers as "strings", this is one way of doing string assignment in C.  If I say

```
ptr = "apple";
```

then no matter where `ptr` used to point, now it points to an array of characters containing the string "apple".  And if I later say

```
ptr = "pear";
```

then `ptr` doesn't point to the string "apple" any more; now it points to a different array of characters containing the string "pear".  You can think of this pointer sort of as if it's assigning all of the characters of the string at once (although that's not actually what it's doing, at all).

So if `*ptr` accesses just one character, and `ptr` is the pointer value itself, then why does the first form

```
char *ptr = "apple";
```

work?

The answer is that when you say

```
char *ptr = "apple";
```

the `*` that shows up in there is not the pointer-indirection operator.  It is not saying that we are trying to access the first character of anything.

When you say

```
char *ptr = "apple";
```

the `*` is saying that `ptr` is a pointer.  It's just like when you say

```
char *ptr;
```

the `*` is saying that `ptr` is a pointer.

C' declaration syntax for pointers is a little weird.  Here's how to think about it.  The syntax is

*type-name*     *thing-that-has-that-type* `;`

So when we say

```
char *ptr;
```

the *type-name* is `char`, and the *thing-that-has-that-type* is `*ptr`.
We're saying that `*ptr` will be a `char`.  And if `*ptr` will be a `char`, that means that `ptr` must be a pointer-to-`char`.

And then, when we say

```
char *ptr = "apple";
```

we're saying that `ptr` (which we've just got done saying is a pointer-to-`char`) should have as its initial value a pointer to an array containing the string "apple".

Answer (score 2):

> `ptr = "apple"; // shouldn't it be *ptr = "apple"`

Starting from the beginning...

The *string literal* `"apple"` is stored in a 6-element array of `char`, like so:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|'a'|'p'|'p'|'l'|'e'| 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The trailing `0` marks the end of the string (it's called the *string terminator*).

When an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" appears in an expression, it will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array, *unless* the array expression is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is used to initialize a character array in a declaration.

Thus, in the statement

```
ptr = "apple";
```

the expression `"apple"` is converted ("decays") from an expression of type "6-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`".  The type of the expression `ptr` is `char *`, or "pointer to `char`"; thus, in the assignment above, `ptr` will receive the address of the first element of `"apple"`.

It should *not* be written as

```
*ptr = "apple";
```

since the expression `*ptr` evaluates to the value of the thing `ptr` points to, which at this point is a) indeterminate, and b) the wrong type for the assignment.  The type of the expression `*ptr` is `char`, which is not compatible with `char *`.

I've written a utility that prints a map of items in memory; given the code

```
char *ptr = "apple";
char arr[] = "apple";
```

the map looks something like this:

```
       Item         Address   00   01   02   03
       ----         -------   --   --   --   --
      apple        0x400c80   61   70   70   6c    appl
                   0x400c84   65   00   70   74    e.pt

        ptr  0x7fffcb4d4518   80   0c   40   00    ..@.
             0x7fffcb4d451c   00   00   00   00    ....

        arr  0x7fffcb4d4510   61   70   70   6c    appl
             0x7fffcb4d4514   65   00   00   00    e...
```

The string literal `"apple"` lives at address `0x400c80`<sup>1</sup>.  The variables `ptr`  and `arr` live at addresses `0x7fffcb4d4518` and `0x7fffcb4d4510`, respectively<sup>2</sup>.

The variable `ptr` contains the value `0x400c80`, which is the address of the first element of the `"apple"` string literal (x86 stores multi-byte values in "little-endian" order, so the least-significant byte comes first, meaning you have to read right-to-left).

Remember the "except" clause above?  In the second declaration, the string literal `"apple"` is being used to initialize an *array* of `char` in a declaration; instead of being converted to a pointer value, the *contents* of the string literal are copied to the array, which you can see in the memory dump.

> 2. `printf("%s", ptr) // Why should I send  the address instead of the value`

Because that's what the `%s` conversion specifier *expects* - it takes a pointer to the first character of a 0-terminated string, and will print out the sequence of characters starting at that location until it sees the terminator.

> 3 ... I can't understand what is supposed to imply

You cannot change the value of an array object.  Let's look at what `str` would look like in memory:

```
     +---+
str: |'Q'| str[0]
     +---+
     |'u'| str[1]
     +---+
     |'e'| str[2]
     +---+
     |'s'| str[3]
     +---+
     |'t'| str[4]
     +---+
     | 0 | str[5]
     +---+
```

You can write to each `str[i]`<sup>3</sup> (changing its value), but you cannot write to `str` because there's nothing to write *to*.  There's no `str` object separate from the array elements.  Even though the *expression* `str` will "decay" to a pointer value, no storage is set aside anywhere for that pointer - the conversion is done at compile time.

Similarly, attempting to modify the contents of a string literal invokes *undefined behavior*<sup>4</sup>; you may get a segfault, *or* your code may work as expected, *or* you may wind up launching nukes at Liechtenstein.  So you can't write to `*p` or `p[i]`; however, you *can* write a new value to `p`, pointing it to a different location.

---

1. Techically, it's `0x0000000000400c80`; the `%p` specifier drops leading zeros.

   Same deal - technically, the values are `0x000000007fffcb4d4518` and `0x000000007fffcb4d4510`.  Note that the specific address values will change from run to run.

   `*str` is equivalent to `str[0]`

   The C language definition identifies certain operations which are erroneous, but doesn't place any requirements on the compiler to handle that code in any particular way.  Different platforms store string literals in different ways; some put them in read-only memory, so attempting to modify them results in a segfault, while other platforms store them in a writable segment so that the operation succeeds.  Some may store them in such a way that you don't get a segfault, but the string isn't changed.