# String to char in Arduino

Tags: c++, string, arduino, char

```
char string2char(String ipString){
  char opChar[ipString.length() + 1];
  memset(opChar, 0, ipString.length() + 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < ipString.length(); i++)
    opChar[i] = ipString.charAt(i);
}
```

Called as `char charssId[AP_NameString.length()+1] = string2char(AP_NameString);`

What is the right way to call the function? Want to change String ssid to char ssid, to make it compatible with esp8266 library.

Comment: Can you describe what the function should do? Looks like stripping the characters one by one from a String object and placing them in a character array. However, the function declaration shows it returns a char, but has no return statement. Your example use shows you expect it to return an array of characters. Can you rethink or describe better what is your question?

Comment: seems rather superfluous to do a `memset` when you anyway overwrite every byte except the last one. however, as your function stands now it doesn't do anything since it doesn't return the results from the function.

Comment: @joH1, no it's c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> char charssId[AP_NameString.length()+1] = string2char(AP_NameString);
> ```

This line is will not work. Because `char charssId[AP_NameString.length()+1]` this means you are declaring an array of certain size and at the same time replacing it with the returned array from the method.

You can do as follows,

```
char* string2char(String ipString){ // make it to return pointer not a single char
  char* opChar = new char[ipString.length() + 1]; // local array should not be returned as it will be destroyed outside of the scope of this function. So create it with new operator.
  memset(opChar, 0, ipString.length() + 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < ipString.length(); i++)
    opChar[i] = ipString.charAt(i);
  return opChar; //Add this return statement.
}

// Now call this as below,
char* charssId = string2char(AP_NameString); // make the variable as pointer so that it can hold an array address.
// use it as a char array.
delete[] charssId; // Remember to delete it after finished using it.
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `delete[] charssId` when you are done using it

Comment: Thanks! I should've mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning pointer to first character of the array from the function and assigning it to the array, this is not possible. [Learn more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array)

To make it work you've got to assign a pointer returned from function to pointer variable -- like following:

```
char* charssId = string2char(AP_NameString);
// Do stuff
delete [] charssId;
```

and then access it like regular array:

```
charssId[index]
```

---

Thats already explained in answer above, so there are several approaches which handles this task easier.

First is [toCharArray()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/tochararray/) method of string class

```
char opChar[ipString.length() + 1];
ipString.toCharArray(opChar, ipString.length());
// Do stuff
delete [] opChar;
```

Second is [c_str()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/c_str/) method of class string (string returned is `const`)

```
const char *unmodificable = ipString.c_str();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with your code.

Your function is declared as returning a *single* `char`, not an *array* of `char`s.  And it is missing an actual `return` statement. But even if it weren't, you would be returning a local array that goes out of scope when the function exits, leaving the caller with a dangling pointer to invalid data.

You are declaring the `opChar` array in a non-standard way known as a "variable-length array".  VLAs are a compiler-specific extension, and thus not portable.  You need to dynamically allocate the array using `new[]` instead.

Try this:

```
char* string2char(const String &ipString){
    char *opChar = new char[ipString.length() + 1];
    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < ipString.length(); i++)
        opChar[i] = ipString.charAt(i);
    */
    ipString.toCharArray(opChar, ipString.length());
    opChar[ipString.length()] = '\0';
    return opChar;
}

char *charssId = string2char(AP_NameString);
// use charssId as needed...
delete[] charssId;
```

A safer option is to use `std::string` instead:

```
std::string string2char(const String &ipString){
    std::string opChar;
    opChar.resize(ipString.length());
    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < ipString.length(); i++)
        opChar[i] = ipString.charAt(i);
    */
    ipString.toCharArray(opChar, ipString.length());
    return opChar;

    // alternatively:
    // return std::string(ipString.c_str(), ipString.length());
}

std::string charssId = string2char(AP_NameString);
// use charssId.c_str() as needed...
```

But a conversion is actually not needed at all:

```
const char *charssId = AP_NameString.c_str();
// use charssId as needed...
```