# const char * const VS const char [] in C

Tags: c, memory

I am using the library `argp` in C and I wonder why the two following things are not equivalent:

Code 1:

```
const char * const doc = "Welcome to my program";
struct argp argp = { NULL, NULL, NULL, doc };
```

Code 2:

```
const char doc[] = "Welcome to my program";
struct argp argp = { NULL, NULL, NULL, doc };
```

The first one does not compile with the error:

> main.c:5:40: error: initializer element is not constant
>   struct argp argp = { NULL, NULL, NULL, doc };
>   main.c:5:40: note: (near initialization for ‘argp.doc’)

But in my mind `const char doc[]` was exactly the same as a constant pointer on char.

Note that both code were tested as global variables so in both case the lifetime of the variables should have been the same.

What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array does that help?

Comment: Both variables are defined globally that's why I am confused about considerations on the stack scope.

Comment: @S.M. Conceptually, yes. The pointer would be pointing at something that is const.

Comment: @CosmoSterin your first version compiles fine for me. I just did it in a main though. So maybe you're not including enough information?

Comment: @S.M. Ok, it does! What happens here is that doc[] will be considered as an alias for a constant (the string "Welcome...") whereas in the second case it will not because it's a variable (no matter the const). That's because the C spec is very strict that behavior would not happen in C++ which is maybe why matt could compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference beween an array and a pointer.

In the first case, `doc` is a pointer, pointing to a block of memory containing that string.
In the second case, `doc` is an array. There is no pointer. doc directly contains the items.

Both can be used when a `(const char*)` is needed somewhere, such as argument to `printf()`. But they are different. For the first, the pointer is passed. For the second, the address of doc is passed. This happens implicitly.

For example, build this little program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

        const char a[] = "abcdefghijkl";
        const char *b = "ijklmnopqrst";

        printf("sizeof(a) = %d\n",(int)sizeof(a));
        printf("sizeof(b) = %d\n",(int)sizeof(b));
        return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
sizeof(a) = 13
sizeof(b) = 8
```

When leaving out the 'const' for now, you could also assign a new pointer to the pointer variable, but not to the array variable.

Comment: a[] will implicitly have a '/0' character at the end. Will that happen for *b?

Comment: The *b = "..."  line will generate a static string in the data segment, and create a pointer-var 'b', sizeof like void* , and pre-init it to the const string. The string has a null-terminator. Sizeof(b) will return 4 or 8 depending on arch.