# C++11 char array intializations and string literals

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers, string-literals

In C++11, `char` pointers cannot be initialized to string literals directly.
In earlier versions of C++, I could do this with no issue.

### If the code below is allowed:

```
char arr[] = "Hello";
char *p_str1 = arr;  //allowed
```

### Then why is the code below not allowed?

```
char *p_str3 = "Hello"; //Not allowed
```

Note: I am aware adding `const` would fix. But I need to know the reasons.

Comment: IMHO The reason is clear from the error message. The second one is like the first one but `const char arr[] = "Hello";`.

Comment: @S.M. Need to know how the first one is different from second

Comment: Related C question: [C: differences between char pointer and array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/)

Comment: @CEPB I'm not aware of any C++ implementation that would perform a heap allocation for either case.

Comment: @CEPB The edits to your comment are making it more wrong, not less. This has nothing to do with the ability to track dynamic memory allocations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char arr[] = "Hello"` stores a modifiable copy of the string literal `"Hello"` in the char array `arr`, the `p_str1` variable is a pointer to that array, since the data is modifiable the pointer does not need to be `const`.

`char *p_str3 = "Hello"` is a pointer directly to a string literal that is read-only. The pointer does not *own* the string literal, more often than not these are stored in some read-only section of memory, either way you can access the data, but you can't modify it. Making the `const` pointer obligatory avoids undesired problems at runtime.

The C++ standard does not allow for non-const pointers to unmodifiable data. And that is fortunate because it avoids undefined behavior by way of attempting to modify it, as often happens in C where this rule doesn't exist.

It was still legal to use non-const `char` pointer in C++03 (perhaps for legacy reasons), when it was deprecated, after C++11 it was disallowed. As far as I can tell attempting to modify these string literals was always undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It's because C++ understands that the string constant will be stored in non-modifiable memory, so it must be flagged as `const`. In many compilers this is stored in a read-only [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment).

Any attempt to modify that string could result in a segmentation fault.

In the first case you're actually making a copy to a local array. This is modifiable.

Comment: How is the first approach different from approach 2. Need clarity. string constant will not be stored in non-modifiable memory then?

Comment: In the first case you're saying "please create a local array that has a copy of the following contents" and on most compilers that's stored on the stack.

Comment: *Any attempt to modify that string could result in a segmentation fault.* or worse. I remember the nefarious and mysterious "Bus Error".