# 2-D character array

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char str[3][10]={
                    "vipul",
                    "ss",
                    "shreya"
};
```

Why this won't work:

```
printf("%s",str[1][0]);
```

If i want to access `str` whereas

```
printf("%s",&str[1][0]);
```

or this would do it perfectly

```
printf("%s",str[1]);
```

Can anyone explain ? 
Why is the first code giving an error

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:9:5: error: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but 
                   argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-   Werror=format]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Why does the argument has type `int`?

Comment: That would be the same as saying `printf("%s", 'a')`. http://codepad.org/0PPoS9BU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("%s",str[1][0]);
```

The problem is in this line. When For `%s` format specifier, printf() expects a pointer to a null terminated string. Whereas `str[1][0]` is simply a char (specifically the first `s` in `"ss"`), which is promoted to int (**default argument promotions**). That's exactly what the error message says.

Comment: Strange that the answer which doesn't answer that why argument has type `int` got the most votes. +1 for you and all similar answers.

Comment: @VipulVerma Technically this answer should be the accepted one .

Answer (score 3):

Well

`str[1]` is a `char*` and `str[1][0]` is a `char`.
But when you use `%s`, `printf()` expect a pointer so you try to cast the char into a pointer.

So your `char` is promoted to an `int`.

Comment: @VipulVerma He didn't answer why it has type `int` ... read other answers carefully.

Answer (score 1):

It is said in the error:

```
format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’
```

and your argument `str[1][0]` is a `char`, not the expected `char *`. In C, a `char` is treated as an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

In first case `printf("%s",str1[1][0]);` you are passing single character to printf function and format specifier that you use it `%s`. For `%s` printf function expects string of character and not character.So it gives error.
As in 1st printf function you are specifying `%s` and you are passing character, argument promotion will takes place and `char` will promoted to `int`.

```
•The default argument promotions are char and short to int/unsigned int and float to double
•The optional arguments to variadic functions (like printf) are subject to the default argument promotions
```

More on [Default argument promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls) and [here](http://gavinsmith87.blogspot.dk/2012/04/notes-on-c-default-argument-promotions.html).

Answer (score 0):

on your line error:

```
 printf("%s",str[1][0]);
```

you try to print a string where you have a character ("%c" in printf)

so to only print one of ur 2D array you would have to do something like that:

```
  int main()
  {
  int i;
  char str[3][10]=
  {
  "vipul",
  "ss",
  "shreya"
  };
  i = 0;
  while(str[0][i] != '\0')
  {
  printf("%c",str[0][i]);
  i++;
  }
  }
```

which is pretty ugly ^^

instead you could print all ur 2D array with 3 single iteration with that:

```
 int main()
 {
 int i;
 char str[3][10]=
 {
 "vipul",
 "ss",
 "shreya"
 };
 i = 0;
 while(i < 3)
 {
 printf("%s\n",str[i]);
 i++;
 }
 }
```