# Strange C function returned variable type behaviour

Tags: c, types, return

I met a behaviour I don't understand.
I want fun to return a 2 byte val.
I create a 4 byte var to do some processing and return the variable.
My assumption is the variable is implicitly converted to short.
However, it appears that the returned value isnt rly 2 byte, because the printf fun prints a value greater than 2^16 unless I place (short) before fun().
Why is that?

```
short fun()
{
long var = 2<<20;
return var;
}

printf("%i", fun());
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls The moral of the story is don't rely on the default behaviour if it's not what you want.

Comment: Also, `var` is uninitialized...

Comment: Your code is returning an uninitialized value first off.

Comment: It's an example, just to explain the problem...

Comment: The code is just an example in my code it is initialized and the problem is that either it is not zero extended or it's not converted to short when being returned from fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you start with `10` and left shift 20 to `1000000000000000000000` which exceeds the range of short and passes it to a function that gets a variadic argument (...)

when printf (and other variadic function) look at the value it is basically just a memory location and it uses the format specifier to cast it back to the original type.  Here is a macro example of what it is basically doing:

```
#define va_arg(ap,type)     (*(type *)(((ap)+=(((sizeof(type))+(sizeof(int)-1)) \
                            & (~(sizeof(int)-1))))-(((sizeof(type))+ \
                            (sizeof(int)-1)) & (~(sizeof(int)-1)))))
```

If you added a format specifier that cast it to short, it could see the casted short.  Aside from that just keep (short)-ing your fun().

Answer (score 3):

Variadic functions such as `printf` perform what are called the *default argument promotions* on their operands.  In particular, integers narrower than `int` (such as `short`) automatically get widened to `int` when they are passed into variadic functions.

One way to get around this is to use the `h` length modifier which says "even though you're dealing with an `int` value, pretend that it's really a `short`".  Then, `printf` will narrow the value back to `short` before formatting the output.  For example:

```
printf("%hi", fun());
```

Comment: This does not explain the behavior. If a `short` value in the `printf` arguments were promoted, then the result would still be a `short` value (in the range -32768 to 32767, as is apparently the case in the OP’s C implementation). It would not produce a larger value.

Answer (score 1):

In `return var;`, the value of `var` is converted to the return type of the function, which is `short`. Since the value is outside the range of `short` in your C implementation, there is an overflow. The C specification does not define what happens when there is integer overflow.

In spite of this, the behavior is a little odd. In the `printf` call, many C implementations would use only 16 bits from `fun()`, promote them to an `int`, and pass them to `printf`. Thus, the output would be “0” in spite of the overflow.

What may be happening in your case is that the compiler implements the conversion to `short` by simply ignoring it and leaving the value in the processor register where it was held for `var` (and uses the same register to return the function value). This is permitted by the C standard because, if the `long` value in the register were in the `short` domain, leaving the bits unchanged produces the same value when interpreted as a `short`. If the `long` value is outside the `short` domain, it does not matter what happens, because the C standard does not define what must happen.

Then the contents of the register are simply passed directly to `printf` as an argument. Again, this is valid because it produces the right result if the value is in the `short` domain and anything is permitted if the `var` value were not in the `short` domain.