# Problems with scanf and doubles

Tags: c, scanf

im having trouble understanding why this occurs:
with the following code;

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() 
    {
        double x=123;

        printf("x is %f. Enter a new value for x.\n", x);
        scanf("%f", &x);
        printf("x is %f\n", x);

        return 0;
    }
```

when you enter 45678 as the new value for x, 'x is 123.000017' is printed.
I know that this is fixed when you use %lf when scanning, but why does this happen when using %f?

Answer (score 3):

> I know that this is fixed when you use %lf when scanning, but why does this happen when using %f?

The difference between `printf` and `scanf` function arguments is that you pass values to `printf`, but to `scanf` you pass pointers (i.e. addresses of values). According to C rules, when a function takes a variable number of arguments, all parameters undergo [*default promotions*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1255818/335858).

One of the promotions is that `float`s get converted to `double`, in the same way that `short`s get converted to `int`. That is why you can use `%f` or `%lf` with `printf`: both types of values are converted by the compiler to `double`, so accessing them is safe.

However, there is no such rule for pointers (and for a good reason: trying to write a `double` into a space of `float` would be undefined behavior). That is why you must differentiate between `%f` and `%lf` when passing parameters to the `scanf` family of functions.

Comment: +1 for coming up with good explanation of `default promotions`

Answer (score 1):

```
 scanf("%f", &x);
```

should be

```
 scanf("%lf", &x);
```

There is a false symmetry for floating points conversion specifiers between `printf` and `scanf`.

Also note that `lf` conversion specifier is equivalent to `f` conversion specifier in `printf` (since c99, it was undefined before).

> I know that this is fixed when you use %lf when scanning, but why does this happen when using %f?

`f` conversion specifier in `scanf` requires an argument of type pointer to `float`. By passing an argument of type pointer to `double` you invoke undefined behavior.