# Array/Pointer and scanf

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic, initialization

I have a problem with my code.
I am creating a dynamic array and ask for some values.
But when I print them on screen, the array seems uninitialized.

```
int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    double *p;
    printf("How much numbers?\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    p = malloc (sizeof(double)*i);
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        printf("Set nr. %d :\n", j);
        scanf("%f", p+j);
    }
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        printf("Nr. %d = %f\n", j, *(p+j));
    }
}
```

I think the problem should be in this line, but i cannot figure out why?

```
scanf("%f", p+j);
```

I also tried this versions of code:

```
scanf("%f", (p+j));
scanf("%f", &p[j]);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with scanf and doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890748/problems-with-scanf-and-doubles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong format specifier for reading a double:

```
    scanf("%f", p+j);
```

Use `%lf` for reading a double:

```
    scanf("%lf", p+j);
```

Your possible confusion arises from the fact that printf() uses `%f` for printing both `float` and `double` while scanf() needs different format specifier. Read this post:

[Why does scanf() need "%lf" for doubles, when printf() is okay with just "%f"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is double *p. You need an array of pointers to type double:

```
double **p;
```

You sill need to do something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    double **p;
    printf("How much numbers?\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    p = (double **)malloc (sizeof(double*)*i);
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        printf("Set nr. %d :\n", j);
        p[j] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
        scanf("%lf", p[j] );
        printf ("p[%d]: %f\n", j, *p[j]);
    }
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        printf("Nr. %d = %f\n", j, *p[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: His original code allocates memory correctly, I don't see why you want to expand a 1-d array to 2-d. And you have added bogus casts to malloc.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
scanf("%f", p+(j*sizeof(double));
```

The pointer p stores the address for the first element of the array. The second element will be at the address:

[First Address] **PLUS** one element. The elements you want are double so there you go!

Comment: no... adding `1` to a pointer makes it point to the next element, regardless of element size. `p+j` (aka. `&p[j]`) is correct.