# Problems with simple use of printf and scanf of double numbers in C

Tags: c

I've made extremely easy program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double x;
    printf("Write your number \n");
    scanf ("%f", &x);
    printf("You've written %f \n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

And as a result strange number appears (no matter what x I give):
"You've written `83096261053132580000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`"

What's wrong with this? This program works fine when I change all numbers into an 'int' type.

Comment: `"%f"` of scanf : use `"%lf"` for double.

Comment: `%f` is for a `float`; you've given it a `double`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with scanf and doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890748/problems-with-scanf-and-doubles)

Answer (score 1):

See what happens when you compile it with warnings enabled:

```
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/so$ gcc -Wall x.c -o x
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:6:9: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat]
```

Change `%f` to `%lf` and the `scanf` and `printf` functions will correctly take a `double`.

Comment: More accurately: `scanf()` does not take a `double`.  `scanf ("%lf", ...)` needs a `double *` and `scanf ("%f", ...)` needs a `float *` as the next parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong specifier for `scanf()`.

With `scanf()`, `"%f"` matches a `float *`, yet coded passed a `double *`.  Use `"%lf"` instead.  Code's `printf()` is fine.  See [Correct format specifier for double in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf)

```
 double x;
 printf("Write your number \n");
 // scanf ("%f", &x);
 scanf ("%lf", &x);
 printf("You've written %f \n", x);
```

A good compiler should have warned of your incorrect code as suggested by @abligh.  Either enable all warnings or consider a new compiler.

---

When scanning, the `&x` must match the proper `scanf()` print specifier.

- `"%f"` matches a `float *`
- `"%lf"` matches a `double *`

The using `printf()` things are easier.  If a `float` or `double` is passed, being a variadic function, `float` is promoted to `double`.

- `"%f"` and `"%lf"` match a `double`

Comment: `%lf` only prints a double since C99; if you work in environments where you might not have a C99-compliant C library then using `%f` for printing increases your "portability" and there's no down-side.

Comment: @Matt McNabb Agreed.  Note: A good use of `"%lf"` for `printf()` is to use the the same format string as `scanf()` in select cases.  There is a risk of portability to compilers that are 15+ years out of date.

Comment: MSVC still didn't support `%zu` as of 2011 at least (although they do have `%lf`)

Answer (score 0):

`%f` is used for `float` type. You should use `%lf` for `double` (Long Float).

Comment: In `scanf()` `"%f"` is matched with a `float *`, not `float`.  In `printf()` `"%f"` is match with a `double`, not `float`.  A `float` passed to variadic function is converted to `double`, thus `printf()` will not receive a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `%lf` for scanf and printf.

In other words, this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double x;
    printf("Write your number \n");
    scanf ("%lf", &x);
    printf("You've written %lf \n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `"%f"` is just fine for OP as part of `double x; ... printf("You've written %f \n", x);`.  OP's problem is only with `scanf()`.

Comment: Apparently you can not read between the lines, because the OP did not know that doubles require `lf` instead of just `f` when one wants to treat the variables as doubles.

Comment: "doubles require lf instead of just f" is incorrect.    With `scanf()`, `"%f"` works with `float*` and `"%lf"` works with `double*`.  This answer assets `%lf` is needed with `printf()` which is incorrect. With `printf()`, either `"%f"` and `"%lf"` work.

Comment: @MightyMouse apparently you are not aware than `%f` is correct for using `double` with `printf` :)

Comment: While it is true that both work, it is much easier as a mnemonic rule, since doubles are like "two floats" (hence doubles), or in other words, long doubles. And besides, when people are using `%f` for doubles with `printf`, this only shows sloppiness. Hope you get it at some point. This guy is learning the language.

Comment: Had this answer suggest "easier as a mnemonic rule" rather than "need to use %lf ... printf.", it would be a reasonable opinion rather than an inaccuracy.  Bringing "in other words, long doubles" further confuses the issue as `long doubles` is a 3rd type of floating point distinct from `float` and `double`.   Using `"%f"` is not necessarily a sign of sloppiness as various compilers, even in 2014, do not yet accept this C99 feature. If you're stuck with a C89 library, "%lf" is undefined.

Comment: Of course `long doubles` was my mistake and I meant `long floats` (but SO did not let me edit the comment when I saw that and then I thought it was much better to see if you were going to comment on that; you did not disappoint me at all; you proved what you are made of). Moreover, you can also work with Eniac if you want to do so. I will not argue further with you.

Comment: Rather than commenting on users, recommend sticking to the content of the questions, answer and comments.  [Be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)